# Charlie, Oscar, Delta, Echo

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

A big part of radio communication is the [NATO Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet), which encodes letters as words to make them easier to understand over comms. Your job, if you wish to accept it, is to print them one by one.

You must print this exact string to stdout:

```
A: Alfa
B: Bravo
C: Charlie
D: Delta
E: Echo
F: Foxtrot
G: Golf
H: Hotel
I: India
J: Juliet
K: Kilo
L: Lima
M: Mike
N: November
O: Oscar
P: Papa
Q: Quebec
R: Romeo
S: Sierra
T: Tango
U: Uniform
V: Victor
W: Whiskey
X: Xray
Y: Yankee
Z: Zulu
```

## Rules:

- Your program takes no input
- Standard loopholes are **Disallowed**.
- If there are any builtins in your language that turn letters to their NATO equivelants, you may not use them (I'm looking at you Mathematica).
- You may have trailing spaces and **one** trailing newline.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67915/8478)

Comment: Yea I saw that one but thought this was different enough @MartinEnder

Comment: @sagiksp No one said it wasn't. :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos How is this a duplicate? It's completely different and the only similarity is that they are both kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: I'm closing this as a dupe because it doesn't have any exploitable structure that would allow custom compression schemes to perform better than built-in compression, and the target challenge is our de facto standard challenge for built-in compression.

Comment: @Mego Is it? The rick roll has so much structure that custom compression probably makes a lot more sense than built-in compression.

Comment: [Closely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/109502/8478) If anything I'd call it a dupe of this one, but it allowed people to choose their own words which actually made compression a lot more possible.

Comment: May I have a leading newline?

Comment: shouldn't the first one be `A: Alpha` ?

Comment: @SeanC: According to wikipedia (see link in question), no. That´s ATIS, not NATO. But then, it should be `Juliett`, not `Juliet` and `X-ray` instead of `Xray`.

Comment: @Titus I removed the dash from xray on purpose because I thought that would complicate any compression trying to decode it, I have no idea how juliet lost a t and for your other question, yes, but just one.

Comment: I found a kind of related [joke language](https://github.com/KristinHamilton/marooned). My favorite example usage is Input: `= pants nopants` Output: `100%, nopants`.

Comment: Didn't know about that one :D @mbomb007

Comment: Brings back memories.  The answer I had to give in military inspection was always "November-oscar-sierra-romeo-hotel-echo-papa-sierra-romeo-echo-delta-november-alpha-romeo, sir."

Comment: See also a related problem with solutions public: http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?International+Radiotelephony+Spelling+Alphabet

Answer (score 18):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>189</s> 186 bytes

```python
i=65
for w in"lfa ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu".split():print'%c: %c'%(i,i)+w;i+=1
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Dc3BCoMwEIThe59iKIiKpdBDe7D4MGu61sUkK2vU@vQ25/mY/5Tu9bwMatgh8eoHgtGmGMm8MNgnghsV@kumCeoHaGKP@BHCmkmCeIUEgkwM3Tj0bFgcGWjOhHt20MDZsBmB4lcRJRcDxKUcHmWZ@MjZI48Tc75dr/dl9pKqup1NYioL16JwZVHJTepmf0vTPc7zDw)**

---

Previous: (this was cool, but I realised the simpler version could be made shorter by a byte)

```python
w=''
i=65
for c in"lfAravOharliEeltAchOoxtroTolFoteLndiAulieTilOimAikEovembeRscaRapAuebeComeOierrAangOniforMictoRhiskeYraYankeEulU":
 w+=c.lower()
 if'_'>c:print'%c: %c'%(i,i)+w;w='';i+=1
```

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 76 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“ṭṡl°ẠkWßġȮRẎ+wḋñȥạġ¢ƊḌ¬kạẠ¦WṡỊƒK⁹ç}⁶hm}Kñ£ɦ/lṇẊɠƓ}pƤ°⁸Ụ.g⁹Ġh9ṁ{f»ḲØAżj€⁾: Y
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AZUAav//4oCc4bmt4bmhbMKw4bqga1fDn8ShyK5S4bqOK3fhuIvDscil4bqhxKHCosaK4biMwqxr4bqh4bqgwqZX4bmh4buKxpJL4oG5w6d94oG2aG19S8OxwqPJpi9s4bmH4bqKyaDGk31wxqTCsOKBuOG7pC5n4oG5xKBoOeG5gXtmwrvhuLLDmEHFvGrigqzigb46IFn//w)**

#### How?

Pretty much just dictionary values and compression. The code between `“` and `»` is just a compressed value that will form the string `"Alfa Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel India Juliet Kilo Lima Mike November Oscar Papa Quebec Romeo Sierra Tango Uniform Victor Whiskey Xray Yankee Zulu"` by looking up all the words (with single space prefixes, except for `"Alfa"`) in Jelly's dictionary (except for `" Xray"` which is not in the dictionary, so the direct string value `" X"` and the dictionary entry `"ray"` are used instead).

The rest of the code does the rest:

```
“...»ḲØAżj€⁾: Y - Main link: no arguments
“...»           - the string described above (really a list of characters)
     Ḳ          - split at spaces
      ØA        - alphabet yield - ['A','B','C', ...,'X','Y','Z']
        ż       - zip - makes a list of lists [['A'],['A','l','f','a']],[['B'],['B','r','a','v','o']], ...]
         j€     - join each with
           ⁾:   - the string ": "
              Y - join with line feeds
                - implicit print
```

Comment: (NOTE: I never programmed in Jelly.) When I see your code I'm wondering two things: 1. You currently loop over the alphabet and join them with the words. Is it possible in Jelly to get the first character of a string, so you loop over the words instead of the alphabet, and join them with first_letter_of_word + ": " + word? And 2. You retrieve all words including spaces and then split by space. Is it possible to inclusive-split by the leading capital letters? No idea if these spaces even give extra bytes in their compressed form or not, and if they can be reduced with my description at 2.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen (1) yes it's possible to use the first letter of each word, however it wont be as short since the alphabet yield is a two-byte atom. (2) yes it's possible to split on capital letters, but surprisingly the compression of the string with no spaces is actually longer (many words with leading spaces are actually *in* the dictionary, as are all of these *with* capitalisation).

Comment: The dictionary doesn't contain leading spaces. However, when decompressing multiple words in a row, the default is to separate them by spaces; the first word won't have a leading space, but all following words will.

Answer (score 11):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 156 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu
[A-Z]
¶$&: $&
G`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#DcpJDoJAEADAO6/wQLjpA7zhhvu@YkxssJEOM9OmmSHyMR/gx9A6V@OFKoOeQMX9HEQRDlBZGKY5j/hthW3EKhuzRTUxD4Kp@xc7I8Vz0rCgApdcoU5QVmUKsoYXbBwmmG5ZI@8IRWAP5skHQxmLPlJqWU45lQXWZ4H6AqZAjJ1y3jVsxzfv@/GDbssPvOjeaZof)

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>102</s> 98 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to *Erik the Outgolfer*

```
”AlfaÐ†vo¼¯¤œ®È¨›trotŠˆƒ‹Š™ÈŸt Kilo´àma—……ÍÐ—Žêpa¼°«Äoµ†Çâgo¸šÉµ Whiskey Xrayµ‹nkeeâ¸lu”#vy¬„: «ì,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#Fc4xCsJAEIXhqyzYegI7aw@g7RZRQ6IrMQbSbRE0FoJoWmUNIqJBLQwkos0Ma@Mt5iJxA6/74eNVJHdtt89xTVIFAt5wh6Pewg1jOJN8@Z7wtfrNvxuSpVYUpRjrwmcd2xXwRDXiJBOSJzNc1UiiP3iZcAM94IqRgNzAuMB0IKDQB1xCzrpDe@pYIet5PKx7OXYsC1Mo3Jm50whCyEjuW8wAWbOq/g)

**Explanation**

Uses dictionary compression for the words in 05AB1E's dictionary.
Uses partial dictionary compression whenever possible for other words.
Plain-text words where neither is possible.

```
#          # split on spaces
 v         # for each word
  y        # push the word
   ¬       # get the first letter of the word
    „:     # push the string ": "
       «   # append this to the letter
        ì  # prepend the result to the word
         , # print with newline
```

Comment: Get it down to 98 using this compressed string instead: `”AlfaÐ†vo¼¯¤œ®È¨›trotŠˆƒ‹Š™ÈŸt Kilo´àma—……ÍÐ—Žêpa¼°«Äoµ†Çâgo¸šÉµ Whiskey Xrayµ‹nkeeâ¸lu”`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Thanks! I was sure I looked for `pa` and `li` in the dictionary but I must have missed them. I didn't consider `ya` and `zu` as words though :)

Answer (score 6):

## Java 7, <s>242</s> <s>225</s> <s>222</s> 217 bytes

```java
void d(){char c=65;for(String s:"lpha ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu".split(" "))System.out.println(c+": "+c+++s);}
```

**Explanation:**

```java
void d(){                          // Method
  char c = 65;                     //  Starting character 'A'
  for(String s : "lpha ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu"
      .split(" "))                 //  Loop over the word-parts
    System.out.println(            //   Print line with:
      c                            //    The current character
      + ": "                       //    + ": "
      + c++ + s                    //    + the current character + word-part (and raise the character afterwards)
    );                             //   End of print line
                                   //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
}                                  // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/b0YOtR)

```java
class M{
  static void d(){char c=65;for(String s:"lpha ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu".split(" "))System.out.println(c+": "+c+++s);}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    d();
  }
}
```

Comment: Should work with Java 5 and all subsequent versions.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, 169 characters

(Heavily based on [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)'s [Python 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112229) solution. If you like the idea, please upvote the original answer.)

```ruby
i=?@
"LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUlietIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu".scan(/.[a-z]+/){|w|puts i.succ!+": "+i+w.downcase}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ruby -e 'i=?@;"LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUlietIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu".scan(/.[a-z]+/){|w|puts i.succ!+": "+i+w.downcase}' | head
A: Alfa
B: Bravo
C: Charlie
D: Delta
E: Echo
F: Foxtrot
G: Golf
H: Hotel
I: India
J: Juliet
```

Answer (score 5):

### PHP, <s>202</s> <s>227</s> <s>196</s> 187 bytes

Thanks to [Dewi Morgan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41364/dewi-morgan) for saving 9 bytes

```
echo preg_replace('/([A-Z])[a-z]+/',"$1: $0\n",AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu);
```

https://repl.it/GMkH/1

---

**Older versions**

Thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) and [insertusernamehere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41859/insertusernamehere) for saving 31 bytes!

```
foreach(preg_split('/\B(?=[A-Z])/',AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu)as$k)echo"$k[0]: $k\n";
```

https://eval.in/749541

Thanks to [insertusernamehere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41859/insertusernamehere) for noticing the output was wrong with the previous version.

```
$a=preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);foreach($a as $k)echo "$k[0]: $k\n";
```

https://repl.it/GKS8/3

```
$a=preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu);foreach($a as $k)echo"$k[0]: $k\n";
```

https://repl.it/GKS8/2

Comment: Why variable `$a`? Just move the entire `preg_split()` call in `foreach`'s parameter. Then none of the spaces around `as` will be necessary anymore.

Comment: Instead of constant `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`, better use its value: `1`. But personally I would tweak the regular expression instead: `/\B(?=[A-Z])/`.

Comment: Thanks @insertusernamehere i'll make that edit now `:D` Still getting used to codegolfing

Comment: That would be one byte shorter with a plain array instead of the `preg_split`.

Comment: Errm no it wouldn´t ... `Echo` needs quotes.

Comment: Are methods like gzinflate(), etc forbidden by the standard loopholes? Feels like you could save a dozen bytes or so by compressing the string.

Comment: Also consider a regex over LfaRavoHarlie - the first letters can be autogen'd by a loop, saving 26 bytes, but possibly at too high a cost.

Comment: 10 characters shorter: `echo preg_replace('/([A-Z])[a-z]+/',"$1 = $0\n",Alfa...Zulu);`

Comment: @DewiMorgan nice one, thanks!

Comment: Then how's about a 178ish? :D `$z=A;foreach([lfa,ravo,...,ulu]as$k)echo"$z: $z$k\n";$z++;`

Comment: Oops, I'd need the curlies on that foreach, adding 2 chars, so it's just as efficient to do `$z=A;foreach([lfa,ravo,...,ulu]as$k)echo"$z: ".$z++."$k\n";`

Comment: You can take it down into the 160s if you're willing to do something like `$z=A;foreach(explode(X,gzinflate('BINARY_GARBAGE'))as$k)echo"$z: ".$z++."$k\n";` where BINARY_GARBAGE is the output of `gzdeflate('lfaXravoXharlieXeltaXchoXoxtrotXolfXotelXndiaXulietXiloXimaXikeXovemberXscarXapaXuebecXomeoXierraXangoXniformXictorXhiskeyXrayXankeeXulu')` You can even knock a further couple chars off by replacing explode() with split(), but then you drop compatibility with PHP7.

Comment: I think technically you should add `<? ` at the beginning, though, for character count for PHP. Alternatively, as with Titus' solution below, find something that can use `<?=` to save on characters wasted by echo...

Comment: @DewiMorgan, you mean exactly like [my solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112303/38392)? I posted that a couple of hours before your comment, by the way.

Comment: @aross Yep, looks like many people beat me to my realizations! I didn't realize until I was several comments in that this was not the only PHP post, though, so for a moment there, I thought I was clever :) Your post, at 162b, is impressive... though I confess to having no clue how it works.

Comment: @DewiMorgan, thanks. I actually changed my implementation to that foreach, but before that I used the same approach as your comment. New method iterates over the chars in the string (by string index), checks whether it's an uppercase char (less than `a`), then prints the char lowercased by setting a bit in the char with binary OR. If it was an uppercase char, prefixes that char with "\nA: A"

Answer (score 5):

## Octave, <s>215</s> <s>210</s> 209 bytes

<s>Saved 5 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo.</s> I saved 4 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo, but changing the approach help me save one more

```
fprintf('%s: %s%s\n',[k=num2cell(65:90);k;regexp('lfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu','[A-Z]','split')]{:})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#DcrJasMwEADQX@nFyIYUSqGFOvTQfd/3pDlM1FE8aKQxIykklH67m9O7vMH1SjG72lSp3apSlb6jGU39YSxh1yJzvb/XHuw0Yz9WXOCqrw07OFZYykkHyoSnyBnObCfnssoq@ULYXUpGvoo/BNdlU/INsdxSgDvyeC9LDHPUh2RBH6GHp4JztM8SUF4IVeEV4kLeIjnR8E42i350lDyuPxXWXxA94qRwMSMzPdqezDamnimbZvbb/jXD8A8)

<s>If I got rid of the spaces, I'd save 25 bytes, but then</s> I'd have to use a regex. The regex itself would cost quite a few bytes, and it would also remove the capital letter of all words, leaving me with the words `lfa, ravo` etc. I would therefore have to concatenate the new strings with the leading characters. All this costs bytes.

**Old explanation:**

```
fprintf('%s: %s\n',      % Print a string with the format "str: str\n"
num2cell(65:90)          % Create a cell array with the numbers 65 - 90, one in each cell
strsplit('Alfa ...       % Split the string on the default delimiter: space
[num2cell();strsplit()]  % Concatenate cell arrays, leaving us with
                         % {'A',    'B'
                         %  'Alfa', 'Bravo'}
[...]{:}                 % Convert the cell array to a comma-delimited vector
                         % 'A', 'Alfa', 'B', 'Bravo' ...
```

Comment: Thanks! [This was a bit messier!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#DcrJTsMwEADQX@ESOZGKBKhCkIpD2fd9belhaibNyGNPNLarVohvDz29y@ubTimkpjRFrLeKWMTvYAZTdxSy37PIXO4P68OdauRGigtcdaUZcwPHCks5aUGZ8BQ5wZlt5VxWSSVdCDeXkpCvwg/Bdd6UdEMst@ThjhzeyxL9HPUhWtBH6OAp4xzts3iUF0JVeIWwkLdAjah/J5tEP1qKDtefCusvCA5xkjmbgZmOtyezjbFjSqaa/Q7rg92/qu//AQ), and three bytes longer...

Comment: Ah, yes, `'split'` would be longer here

Comment: `'split'` was shorter: [209 :)](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#DcrJasMwEADQX@nFyIYUSqGFOvTQfd/3pDlM1FE8aKQxIykklH67m9O7vMH1SjG72lSp3apSlb6jGU39YSxh1yJzvb/XHuw0Yz9WXOCqrw07OFZYykkHyoSnyBnObCfnssoq@ULYXUpGvoo/BNdlU/INsdxSgDvyeC9LDHPUh2RBH6GHp4JztM8SUF4IVeEV4kLeIjnR8E42i350lDyuPxXWXxA94qRwMSMzPdqezDamnimbZvbb/jXD8A8)

Comment: I see! Well done!

Comment: You can split on spaces and [save 5 more bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#Dc3LasMwEIXhVzkbIxu8KCkt1KFPknYxUUfxoMuYkRwSSp/d1fp8nP8Im0lpYXRDXTDUoX4VN1/iZ9nzyXNK4/vb8vEynePZ@MaPbXQpEIzuipUsCYNTI/hVoY9m2qApQBsnlB8h7J00SFJIJkhk6J3zlQ3Vk4G2TvjKHpq5GzYjULkpigS1DPFNDavUyM@effYxMvfb3c2vp9nVLUlz0/fv8jcdxz8)

Comment: ... or [go back to `strsplit`](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#Dc3BasMwEIThV5mLsQ09hEIDdeiTpD1slFW9aKU1Kzk0lD67q/N8zH/EzaW0OI1DXTDUoX6W8eWaPsqeXwOrTue35f00X9KlNq@bSptGjQSnh2ElV2GwNkJYDfbT3BpMI6yxotyFsHfSIGqQTJDEsAfnGztqIAdtnfCNAyxzN@xOoPJtKBLNMyQ0c6xSEz979tnHxNxv93H@@l3@5uP4Bw)?

Comment: Thanks again Luis, but maybe you [should post it yourself](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11710/31516) since it's quite different...? (I _do_ appreciate the tips though, don't misunderstand me)

Comment: No,  it's quite similar to your approach. Post it yourself if you want :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 178 bytes

```
"Alfa Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel India Juliet Kilo Lima Mike November Oscar Papa Quebec Romeo Sierra Tango Uniform Victor Whiskey Xray Yankee Zulu"ṇ₁{hw": "w?ẉ}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#DcpLUsJQEAXQrdzKMpxQgAiI/L86a0LHdOUlbXVeAhTFACaUMzfjQHcTNhI941MHTRcRWkaloh2TOWE8svOEThgrnvTgTT266iL01LNDP9sJ4bn4nx4DcYoXSQlDSRgjLTndsmGch2SY0AdhWvCWQ8w0ZcVc2IywoOxdscwkUkuxktCrYR1LnvARG6MjXilLmPFWuCKofm736@UU74MHBPtG9ft5rr6/6voP)

#### Explanation

```
"…"ṇ₁               Split the string on spaces
     {         }ᵐ   Map on each word:
      hw              Write the first letter
        ": "w         Write ": "
             ?ẉ       Write the word followed by a new line
```

Answer (score 4):

## C (MinGW, Clang), 218 bytes

*Thanks to @gastropner!*

```
i;f(){char s[]="lfa:ravo:harlie:elta:cho:oxtrot:olf:otel:ndia:uliet:ilo:ima:ike:ovember:scar:apa:uebec:omeo:ierra:ango:niform:ictor:hiskey:ray:ankee:ulu";for(i=64;++i<91;)printf("%c: %c%s\n",i,i,strtok(i^65?0:s,":"));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc/RasMwDAXQ93xFMAQS2sEGW2HXK/2QbgPVUxYRxyq2W1ZKvz2T9CYddFF4CpHS77qKH/vhHibKbTl@7V0cCZmuCptEYXCshDAp9K9mrdA4QitHpB8hXIxUSFTIQpCZoVdeTpxRAmXQ2QifOEAXNsM5EyxWkWTUvEBC1YxJysw3i73Zcma2sxfnDfSy3736zUY@3l/8cM6S6ti7LqDtQlc@k9uKdam56tzL9@7t8IyydXDD4B@r6XYhSf3Q3JvWyj71zWP9Bw)

## C, <s>259</s> 236 bytes

```
i;f(){char*s="lfa\0ravo\0harlie\0elta\0cho\0oxtrot\0olf\0otel\0ndia\0uliet\0ilo\0ima\0ike\0ovember\0scar\0apa\0uebec\0omeo\0ierra\0ango\0niform\0ictor\0hiskey\0ray\0ankee\0ulu";for(i=64;++i<91;s+=strlen(s)+1)printf("%c: %c%s\n",i,i,s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY/disMgEEbv8xQhENDNFiwsC1s3b@KNdcdmiD9FbWkpffbsF4URz3dkRne4OLdtrL2QL7fY8lHnIXhrVLH3bBRIYDKKQgNzC1B@tJIbzuBRGgWj0h8jvcEE5wCJIwCveJnvFM9UjKrOotrrbtKZHKJIu0qlgNl0wSWxzyUCupZhL1xXeu7DPHdjJdrb3AYNS/D8/aWniX9/jrpOc20lUBJVTkd5LZyaF8PoTv3oxmrS8MnYVer3hqiPlpOQ3avrsfB33b23fw)

Comment: How would I compile this?

Comment: @ItayGrudev, GCC and Clang should both compile that as is. `gcc src.c` or `clang src.c`. Here's a sample run with a main function added so the code will actually link and run: http://ideone.com/4Eowlh

Comment: @chris Then at the expense of 4 bytes, shouldn't `f` be replaced with `main` so the code is valid, or am I missing some golfing convention.

Comment: @ItayGrudev, The way I see it, the question only asked for the functionality, not a full, self-contained program.

Comment: **218** with strtok() and some fiddling with the string `i;f(){char s[]="lfa:ravo:harlie:elta:cho:oxtrot:olf:otel:ndia:uliet:ilo:ima:ike:ovember:scar:apa:uebec:omeo:ierra:ango:niform:ictor:hiskey:ray:ankee:ulu";for(i=64;++i<91;)printf("%c: %c%s\n",i,i,strtok(i^65?0:s,":"));}` Unclear if it works everywhere: TIO segfaults but works in MinGW at least. Can't see much of a reason why it _wouldn't_ work.

Comment: @gastropner Thanks! It works with MinGW on my computer too, and seems to work also on TIO with Clang (but not with gcc or tcc).

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>188</s> <s>186</s> <s>180</s> 174 bytes

no trailing spaces, one leading newline

```php
<?=preg_filter("#[A-Z]#","
$0: $0",AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu);
```

simply replaces all uppercase letters in the compressed string with
`<newline><letter><colon><space><letter>`

Comment: This time [competitive](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112238/29637) ? ;)

Comment: -13 bytes with `gzinflate`-ing the result of `gzdeflate(Alfa...Zulu)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, no leading newline is allowed, only a (single) trailing newline

Comment: @aross: see the OP´s comment from yesterday: `and for your other question, yes, but just one.`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>186</s> 182 bytes

```python
print''.join('\n%s: '%c*('['>c)+c for c in'AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Dc1JDoJAEADAr3AhI5r4AA8m7vu@L5d2bKRlmCbNQOT1yL2SqlIh65Rqf5lsQz2tn3U85etmQz1UVwct7YUsnvbIqp4JoS9Q8CACMYRDNA5GOuIx/5ywm7AJp@zQzOybYJ7XxC3I8JISWFGMay4weaFsMg2yhRR2Ob5Q7zlBPhCKwBHsh0@W6jI5k3Ysl4iyGMurQHkDGyPec5OroKr@)

Comment: see comments on question: one leading newline is (now) accepted

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice stuff.

Answer (score 3):

## Gema, 168 characters

```
\A=@subst{?<J>=\?: \$0\\n;AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu}@end
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '\A=@subst{?<J>=\?: \$0\\n;AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu}@end' | head
A: Alfa
B: Bravo
C: Charlie
D: Delta
E: Echo
F: Foxtrot
G: Golf
H: Hotel
I: India
J: Juliet
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>224</s> <s>205</s> <s>188</s> 180 bytes

Thanks to [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma) for removing 17 bytes, and [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for 8 bytes.

```bash
set {A..Z}
for i in lfa ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu;{ echo $1: $1$i;shift;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#Fc0xDsIwDIXhnVO8gbkSK524BpsbHGI1iZGTVlRVz17M4Mm/3nc27tgfw/A8LlENAqnIkWC0KhJZFgbnTghJod9u2qE5Qjtn1JcQFk86JCukEGRm6MplYkMLZKCPJzxxgBb2hs0IVN@KKi4WSOgOJ2kzb85u/pyZfXYZd/Cfvd7uflcZW5LYx@M8fw)

Comment: [Some golfing](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#Hc1BDoJADIXhvad4ISw0JhxA4sJraFiUsUjDzNSUgUgIZ8fRXZP@ed9O1@N6q6r7djp0ahBIhO8IRrOiJ/PCYJ8IrlfoJ5kmqO@giT3iUwhTThLEKyQQZGDozKFlw@jIQO@ccMsOGjg3bEag@FJEyWKAuJThXsaBl8wu@Tkw59mpXsE/tihXerhmu@B/nM/NVkpRb/v@BQ)

Comment: Indexing array `a` is too long. `set {A..Z};for i in lfa … ulu;{ echo $1: $1$i;shift;}`

Answer (score 3):

## x86 Assembly, 512 bytes

Compiled with NASM and tested with QEMU. To boot you need to put a 2 byte boot signature at the end of the bootsector (510 bytes into the file) so I lost 317 bytes filling the compiled code with zeros. This is my first golf so I have to apologize for any gigantic errors.

```
[org 7c00h]     ;So NASM can change the labels into memory locations correctly.

cld             ;Tells lodsb to look forward in memory

mov bh, 65      ;Moves the ASCII value of A into the BH register
mov si, NATO    ;Moves the first byte of NATO into the si register
call print      ;Call the 'print' subroutine

jmp $            ;Loops forever

print:
    mov ah, 0eh ;Moves the hex value 0E into the AH register. Tells interrupt 10h that we want subfucntion 0E
    lodsb       ;Load a byte of SI into AL and increments a register (DL i think) that tells it the offset to look at

    cmp al, 3   ;Compares the AL register that now has a byte from our string to ASCII value 3 (Enf Of Text)
    je R        ;If AL == 3 then jump to R

    cmp al, 0   ;Comapre AL to ASCII 0 (NULL)
    je newWord  ;If AL == 0 hump to newWord
    int 10h     ;Execute interrupt 10h Subfunction 0Eh (stored in AH register) which prints character value in AL
    jmp print   ;Jump to print

newWord:
    mov al, 10  ;Move ASCII 10 (New Line) into AL
    int 10h     ;Print character

    mov al, 13  ;Move ASCII 13 (Carriage Return) into AL
    int 10h     ;Print character

    mov al, bh  ;Move BH (which has our starting letter) into AL
    int 10h     ;Print Character

    mov al, 58  ;Move ASCII 58 (:) into AL
    int 10h     ;Print Character

    mov al, 32  ;Move ASCII 32 (Space) into AL
    int 10h     ;Print Character

    mov al, bh  ;Move BH into AL
    int 10h     ;Print Character

    inc bh      ;Increments BH by one (BH++)
    jmp print   ;Jump to print

R:
    ret         ;Returns from a subroutine

;Below defines bytes (db) of our string to print. I used 0 as word seperators and 3 to end the string.
NATO: db 0,"lfa",0,"ravo",0,"harlie",0,"elta",0,"cho",0,"oxtrot",0,"olf",0,"otel",0,"ndia",0,"uliet",0,"ilo",0,"ima",0,"ike",0,"ovember",0,"scar",0,"apa",0,"uebec",0,"omeo",0,"ierra",0,"ango",0,"niform",0,"ictor",0,"hiskey",0,"ray",0,"ankee",0,"ulu",3

times 0200h - 2 - ($ - $$) db 0 ;Zerofill the file with upto 510 bytes (This is where all my bytes are)
dw 0AA55H   ;Write the bootsignature
```

### Output

This is what the above code outputs. As you can see *A: Alfa* is missing and that is because the prompt is 25 lines tall...
[image: Above codes output]

To prove I printed *A: Alfa* I replaced `0,"ulu"` with `32,"Z: Zulu"` so that Zulu is one on the same line as Yankee.
[image: Changed code]

I would appreciate it if someone told me if I would be able to  subtract the 317 bytes of zerofill from my code so it would be 195 bytes. Also if this is even valid because the output won't fit on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, <strike>216 187 184 180</strike> 174 bytes

```
"AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu".replace(/[A-Z]/g,`
$&: $&`).trim()
```

Saved a byte thanks to Neil. Saved 5 bytes thanks to ETHproductions.

```js
console.log("AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu".replace(/[A-Z]/g,`
$&: $&`).trim());
```

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 127 bytes

```
`AlfaBŸvoC•r¦eDeltaE®oFoxÉ•GolfHÇUI˜iaJªietKiloL‹aMikeNovem¼rOs¯rPapaQue¼cRo´oSi€ŸTÂ
UnifŽmVÅ¡rW–skeyXŸyY„keeZªu`r"%A""
$&: $&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#AZsAZP//YEFsZmFCwp92b0PClXLCpmVEZWx0YUXCrm9Gb3jDicKVR29sZkjDh1VJwphpYUrCqmlldEtpbG9MwothTWlrZU5vdmVtwrxyT3PCr3JQYXBhUXVlwrxjUm/CtG9TacKAwp9Uw4IKVW5pZsKObVbDhcKhclfClnNrZXlYwp95WcKEa2VlWsKqdWByIiVBIiIKJCY6ICQm//8teA)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to obarakon.

Comment: I was wondering how else you could get rid of that leading newline - it would have actually been a byte cheaper than your previous approach to manually prepend `A: A` to the string. But you can still save another byte by using a literal newline character instead of `\n`.

Comment: Nice answers. You can use a literal newline in Japt as well. Also, replace accepts a string for its second argument and replaces any `$&`s in it with the match, so you can do e.g `"\n$&: $&"` for both langs instead of using functions.

Comment: You can change `@"\n{X}: {X}"}` in Japt to just `"\n$&: $&"` :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice answer! You can save a couple bytes by dropping the `" x` and inserting a `-x` flag into the input. Note that the flag adds 1 byte to the total bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 198 bytes

```python
for x in'Alfa Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel India Juliet Kilo Lima Mike November Oscar Papa Quebec Romeo Sierra Tango Uniform Victor Whiskey Xray Yankee Zulu'.split():print x[0]+': '+x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Dc67bsJAEAXQX7mdiZAQNV2AQIDwDK@AKAZnjEde71jjNTJfb9yf4jSJGmqIjz5dQhgaPRWjlMwJY8wuEL7iVDHROpgGTNUl@NbADjP/L4R51cqAhTjFj@SEpWSMlT45v7NhXcZk2FBB2FZ85xg7zVnxK2xG2JN/KA5e2kaOo8Sh7ZxSKTN@4Wz0wh/5jBmXylVRryychM7HoDDxAfW1f@tGA0Tdumne)

Not exciting or clever. Just loops through the list and prints the first letter then ': ' then the whole word.

Answer (score 2):

### Lua, <s>278</s> 260 bytes

Thanks again to [Manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for saving 18 bytes!

```
function f(w)print(w.sub(w,0,1)..": "..w)end
f"Alfa"f"Bravo"f"Charlie"f"Delta"f"Echo"f"Foxtrot"f"Golf"f"Hotel"f"India"f"Juliet"f"Kilo"f"Lima"f"Mike"f"November"f"Oscar"f"Papa"f"Quebec"f"Romeo"f"Sierra"f"Tango"f"Uniform"f"Victor"f"Whiskey"f"Xray"f"Yankee"f"Zulu"
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#FY27bsMwDEX3fkWgyQYCoV27NU3fr7RJ@tpkhaoJy2JAS3Hz9Q45nQNeXnIKJfmMlGahGus9Y8rVaIfSVOP8fH5RW2suZ8basYa0OwvmKgZnglmwO5DwunUcEcSWELMmN77V4Jb@M1MWu6MYBPeUIQof0g5177FIT/MnjFp4xl7HL9jptVc6QN8Ai74N3ilXbq8L7wUa8CIf1IMW1wjMmmxc@tPBNmEg7sU@0WfS7leLQwdHsW92ih@XOtBHvyUWM00n)

---

**Older versions**

```
a={"Alfa","Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Echo","Foxtrot","Golf","Hotel","India","Juliet","Kilo","Lima","Mike","November","Oscar","Papa","Quebec","Romeo","Sierra","Tango","Uniform","Victor","Whiskey","Xray","Yankee","Zulu"}
for i=1,26 do print(a[i].sub(a[i],0,1) .. ": " .. a[i]) end
```

https://repl.it/GK8J

First time doing Lua, do probably can golf more, but thought I'd add it as an answer anyways.

Comment: [My question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/112208/charlie-oscar-delta-echo#comment273343_112210) may become boring, but again: Why variable `a`? ;) You can move the entire array declaration inside the `for`. And the `for`..`in` syntax helps to avoid writing those long array indices: http://pastebin.com/rxck79md Weird Lua thing: if you declare a function and call it 26 times “manually” (I mean, not in a loop) is shorter: http://pastebin.com/FMF9GmLJ

Comment: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` for the simple reason that I never used Lua before so I was just following the manual to try make it work, aha. Thanks @manatwork for the info, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>187</s> 185 bytes

```powershell
0..25|%{($a=[char]($_+65))+": $a"+(-split'lfa ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu')[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#Dc3RCoJAEIXhVznERooUEdRF0JNIyLSNObjryLhJUT277fX5OP@y3@0Ox@/6Uzi61L4juxauqU7HsqxWZzhaVcV2GoOkTWgJRrMioyAMDongO4W@kmmChhaaOGC4C@GZSYIEhUSC9AydOd7YMHky0JgJ39hDI2fDZgQaHopBWrUI8UkNnUw9v3P2nceeOd8@N2XtmutvWf4)

Loops from `0` to `25`, each iteration forming `$a` of the corresponding capital `char`. Then string-concatenated with `: $a` (i.e., the colon-space-letter). Then that string is string-concatenated with an string that's formed by indexing into an array created by `-split`ting the phonetic string on spaces. Each of those 26 strings is left on the pipeline, and an implicit `Write-Output` happens at program completion, inserting a newline between elements.

*Saved two bytes thanks to @Matt.*

Comment: Nice. Removing the first character of each word didn't even occur to me. You can chop off 2 bytes doing this: `0..25|%{($a=[char]($_+65))+": $a"+(-split'lfa ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu')[$_]}`

Comment: @Matt Oh sure, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <strike>184 bytes</strike> <strike>179 bytes</strike> 178

```
<?=preg_filter('/(.)[a-z]+/',"$1: $0
",AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu);
```

saved a single byte by using preg_filter instead of preg_replace.

---

*Original answer* <strike>184 bytes</strike> 179 bytes

```
for($c=A;$s=[lfa,ravo,harlie,elta,cho,oxtrot,olf,otel,ndia,uliet,ilo,ima,ike,ovember,scar,apa,uebec,omeo,ierra,ango,niform,ictor,hiskey,ray,ankee,ulu][+$i++];$c++)echo"$c: $c$s
";
```

uses the fact that its sorted to generate the first char on the fly.

5 bytes saved by @Titus.

Comment: Golf your original down to 180-1 with `for($c=A;$s=[lfa,...,ulu][+$i++];$c++)echo"$c: $c$s\n";`. Nice regex though.

Comment: @Titus I had in mind there must be a better way but switched to preg. Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 2):

### [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 165 bytes

This script is based on the [Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112209/59010) by Martin Ender.

```sed
s/$/AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu/
s/[A-Z]/\n&: &/g
s/.//
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#Dcq5EoIwEADQ3q@wcOg0vR3e932iFgsusEOSdZaEka9H2zevKVVHhTqFgUDFwxxEE45QOxgnOU/464TdlHU6Y4d6bt8EC/8vbkmaV2RgTQVuuEITo2zLBGQHH9h7jDE5sEE@EorACWzGZ0spi7lQ4liuOZUF1jeB@g62QIy89qpVqkfYjV7qaYN@O1DZH3pKNc0P)**

**Explanation:**

```sed
s/$/AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu/
   # generate the alphabet words in concatenated form
s/[A-Z]/\n&: &/g
   # prepend '\nUL: ' before each upper-case letter (UL), getting the needed format
s/.//
   # delete the leading newline, plus implicit printing at the end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 91 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
╗D↕«∙φā¡75↔TI.½!γΜΧ…¡%<F┼0h╔κy|▓@TņV≈%⁹cr_σy░mgļΕžΕ⅝ »τ{M╔|«▼↔»aΓ²⁹┘′⅓G…└g↔bFΞ‽‘θ{KUtƧ: ooo
```

Explanation:

```
...‘θ{KUtƧ: ooo  that gibberish is a compressed string                 
...‘             push the compressed string of the words
    θ            split on spaces
     {           for each
      K          pop the 1st letter off & push it
       U         uppercase it
        t        output in newline a copy of the letter
         Ƨ: o    append ": "
             o   append the alphabet letter
              o  append the rest of the word
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 184 bytes

```bash
printf '%c: %s
' {Alfa,Bravo,Charlie,Delta,Echo,Foxtrot,Golf,Hotel,India,Juliet,Kilo,Lima,Mike,November,Oscar,Papa,Quebec,Romeo,Sierra,Tango,Uniform,Victor,Whiskey,Xray,Yankee,Zulu}{,}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#DcrLUoNAEAXQvV/BJsXmfoE7ExM1T6N5aHadSRO6GKapZqBCUXw7etZnrExCzJJ04p6TSf2UJv2LzwhTo1Yxy8m8MF7ZR8Lc5YqFPqJpxJv6DO8a2eMj3ISwbP5nxEq8Yi0lYSMFY6stl1c27GpHhk@qCPuGr@zwpSUrvoXNCAcKd8UxSKZW4iQuquGcS11whx@jDr8UCmZcGt8MPYZx/AM)

Comment: +1. The `{,}` trick in the brace expansion is a very clever way to double up each list member!

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 177 bytes

```lua
print(("AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu"):gsub('%u',"\n%1: %1"):sub(2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#Fcq5DoJAEADQXzEkREhstKTzvu/b2Aw4wIRlhwy7RL4esX15TSGkjec5QxXDSKDicQqiCCeoDEyjlGf8NcJmzipesEG11B@ClW2LWZPiDeWwpQx3XGEeouzLCOQABRwthhidOEc@E4rABXTCV00xS36jyLDcUyozrB8C9RN0hviyyjp@kJQ29Lqu7fact3b7Qcftt/rHge83zQ8)

**Without trailing newline, 180 bytes:**

```lua
io.write(("AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu"):gsub('%u',"\n%1: %1"):sub(2))
```

**Explanation**

```lua
str = "AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu"
str = str:gsub('%u',"\n%1: %1") -- returns "\nA: Alfa...". %u matches uppercase letters, %1 returns matched letter in this case.
str = str:sub(2) -- remove added newline in the beginning
print(str) -- native print command
```

It uses Lua's string.gsub substitution function to pattern match the uppercase letters.
The letters are then replaced with the requested format (plus the letters themselves). Newlines are also added on the same pass.

The sub-function at the end just trims out newline from the beginning and also works nicely to hide the second return value of gsub, which would have been the amount of replacements.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>175</s> <s>171</s> <s>164</s> 162 bytes

Note: no longer requires compressed file, uses IBM-850 encoding.

```
for($l=A;$c=LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUlietIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu[$i++];)echo$c<a?"
$l: ".$l++:"",$c|~▀;
```

Run like this:

```
php -nr 'for($l=A;$c=LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUlietIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu[$i++];)echo$c<a?"
$l: ".$l++:"",$c|~▀;';echo
```

## Explanation

Prints every character individually (lowercased by OR with a space). If an uppercase character is encountered, it first prints a string of the form "\nA: A".

## Tweaks

- Saved 4 bytes by using another compression strategy
- Saved 7 bytes by using a different delimiter (to combine assignment of `$l` with explode param), and not preventing a leading newline
- Saved 2 bytes with a new method

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>216</s> <s>215</s> 212 bytes

```c
i=64,l;f(){for(char*s="lfAravOharliEeltAchOoxtroTolFoteLndiAulieTilOimAikEovembeRscaRapAuebeComeOierrAangOniforMictoRhiskeYraYankeEulU";++i<91;printf("%c: %c%.*s%c\n",i,i,l,s,s[l]+32),s+=l+1)for(l=0;s[++l]>90;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#FY9RS8MwFEbf@ytKodAuQTYVYcYKQeqTEijzYcw9ZNmtvfQ2GUlahLHfXivf03k655uxenrkJNqivLbOF6bTfhWqjFrp9aQWIqyBojSdcr/Ru52jdxfhw55RjoSwQ1I4SOxrN8FwgiYY3eiLHOEEb24AheC91PZHWVwEn2iiazoMPey93mvbQz3SVyYYw5ftRlw82tgWWW6e09zkd6uQm2@bcVxGPPBwoCN7uC95YBWxTfnfTNVahANjdHzdrkUpbkkyOTyng0ZblOk1SdPlnkhu8/wH)

A detailed, human readable, well commented and perfectly valid (no compiler warnings) version of the program can be found below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Uppercase characters designate the last character of a word
    char*s="lfAravOharliEeltAchOoxtroTolFoteLndiAulieTilOimAikEovembeRscaRapAuebeComeOierrAangOniforMictoRhiskeYraYankeEulU";

    int i = 64; // Consecutive character
    int l; // Word length

    // Loop `i` from A to Z; Shift `s` with word length
    // `s` always points to the beginning of a word
    for( ; ++i < 91; s += l + 1 ) {
        // Increment `l` until you reach the next capital letter
        for( l = 0; s[++l] > 90 ;);
        // Print the current character, the word without it's last letter
        // and the last letter lowercased
        printf( "%c: %c%.*s%c\n", i, i, l, s, s[l]+32 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Comment: @ceilingcat Not only the `char*s` but the `printf` could go in there too. Thus saving another 3 bytes - a semicolon and 2 curly braces as we no longer need them since there is only one instruction in it's body - the other `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <strike>257</strike> 242 bytes

*Thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for saving 15 bytes!*

```
class P{static void Main(){var c='A';foreach(var t in "lfa ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu".Split())System.Console.WriteLine(c+": "+c+++t);}}
```

Full program which prints the required text, with one trailing newline.

Ungolfed:

```
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var c='A';
        foreach(var t in "lfa ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu".Split())
            System.Console.WriteLine(c+": "+c+++t);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually 17 bytes longer than the output... :P

Comment: @StewieGriffin: It's a full program, and C# didn't win awards for being minimalistic :P

Comment: I know, it was just an observation :)

Comment: You can golf it to 242 bytes [like this](https://ideone.com/ZiW4OD).

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>216</s> 214 bytes

```
`A: Alfa
B: Bvo
C: Cr¦e
D: Delta
E: E®o
F: FoxÉ
G: Golf
H: HÇU
I: Iia
J: Jªiet
K: Kilo
L: La
M: Mike
N: Novem¼r
O: Os¯r
P: Papa
Q: Que¼c
R: Ro´o
S: Si
T: TÂ
U: Unifm
V: VÅ¡r
W: Wskey
X: Xy
Y: Ykee
Z: Zªu
```

Explaination: 
There is most likely a much better way to do it, but since i'm new I don't know it.
I basically compressed the string with Oc" and put that string to be decompressed using Od"

If someone wants to help me save bytes by using something different from line breaks, I'd be happy to learn!

edit: Saved 2 bytes using ` instead of Od"

Comment: Using [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#BcE5TsNAGAXg/p3ineN12fc9zlYxin5LIzsMchYlbSSEOAYNRQpoKFOND2a@r3qpibU8daiL9UtAQ2wU8dvQFJuWnxxaYiv@BLTFdriWn@iInZCn6Ird8iNBT@x5h77Yjw9vJwzEgc8DhuLQYSSOfGYYi@NwsUN8FpiIk2P8LTAVp@7NYSbOzhafe8zFeYh/AQtx4bEUl@UdiZi8@vSAlbgq3@NXgbW4PmZ2w0bc3LAVt5kZduIuPs5V9Q8 "Japt – TIO Nexus") it doesn't give the desired result `:/`

Comment: @ʰᵈˑyes that could be, I didn't have enough time to check everything before I had to go to work. I might do it again (and better) after work.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ There are some unprintables in the string which don't show up in the Markdown. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#BcG5SgNhGAXQ/j7FfY7bZd/3TLbKIfwDw0z8ZbJgOhFFRLCL2A02Fim0sUz1zYPFc643JbGURiHKYtnyg0dFrNgps2@Hqlh16S5ETazZj0ddrPv74tVOaIgNn0Zois3iJUBLbNlnHKIttu0cux06YidOPbpi195C9MRenDj0xb4/uI1dMgzEwdZ@MwzFYXgXYiSO9s4ua4zFsbc/j4k4ie3BckzFafEIBGJwG0f2vsFMnBXP9pVhLs7tY5u4IxbiwvIjluLSnhLnsBJXdt5fr/8)

Comment: @ETHproductions ah thanks for that, I didn't know

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 89 bytes

```
.d⻵㡺ᐒଆຳ뼙΋ÒΗ䊊繎ㅨڨǔᯍⰬᐓ❤ᄵ㤉ተ᤬䆰髨⨈性dc Fl5DhRJ":
```

Comment: Do these characters happen to be in a specific single byte character set?

Comment: TIO gives a bad eval error and reports 161 bytes in the message. Either Pyke needs pushing there or something went wrong with a copy and paste here. @Adám if it was 1-1 it would be 41 bytes, utf-8 would be 88, but something definitely looks a bit off.

Comment: @JonathanAllan it should be UTF-8. TIO runs it in not UTF-8. I think the byte-count might be wrong because it's measured as UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

## Qbasic, 383 bytes

Not impressive, but for what it's worth:

```
dim a(1to 26)as string
a(1)="lfa
a(2)="ravo
a(3)="harlie
a(4)="elta
a(5)="cho
a(6)="oxtrot
a(7)="olf
a(8)="otel
a(9)="ndia
a(10)="uliet
a(11)="ilo
a(12)="ima
a(13)="ike
a(14)="ovember
a(15)="scar
a(16)="apa
a(17)="uebec
a(18)="omeo
a(19)="ierra
a(20)="ango
a(21)="niform
a(22)="ictor
a(23)="hiskey
a(24)="ray
a(25)="ankee
a(26)="ulu
for i=1to 26
?chr$(i+64);": ";chr$(i+64);a(i)
next
```

Comment: Old BASIC memories… Can't those be stored in a `data` statement then `read` inside the `for`..`next` loop?

Comment: @manatwork, that's a good idea; I hadn't thought of it!

Comment: Wouldn't simply `?"A: Alfa"` and so on be only 360 bytes?

Comment: @oerkelens, you could be right.  I didn't even consider the possibility.  :)

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 220 bytes

```
/;/: /A;Alfa
B;Bravo
C;Charlie
D;Delta
E;Echo
F;Foxtrot
G;Golf
H;Hotel
I;India
J;Juliet
K;Kilo
L;Lima
M;Mike
N;November
O;Oscar
P;Papa
Q;Quebec
R;Romeo
S;Sierra
T;Tango
U;Uniform
V;Victor
W;Whiskey
X;Xray
Y;Yankee
Z;Zulu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#Dcs5coNAEAXQ/J/CNyD3j7Tv@66shRszxUC7WoPKOj32y1@XMfv8yHrsxULQZ9/lZRhwUIrHoBhyqDEJRhzlpWHMsf0mt4QJJxYLTDm1pBEzzpqvIJhz3v6/hAUXIRqWXIZasOIqVIo11/bS@qGODTfPXBxbbuVHsOOu1Yfm2HNvtRoOPAR1Fxx5lObbcOKpCYV5jTPPIU/muPBShmelb1x5dXnjxps0lSruvLex7bo/)

-20 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions.

Comment: It's not hard, and it saves 20 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#Dcs5coNAEAXQ/J/CNyD3j7Tv@66shRszxUC7WoPKOj32y1@XMfv8yHrsxULQZ9/lZRhwUIrHoBhyqDEJRhzlpWHMsf0mt4QJJxYLTDm1pBEzzpqvIJhz3v6/hAUXIRqWXIZasOIqVIo11/bS@qGODTfPXBxbbuVHsOOu1Yfm2HNvtRoOPAR1Fxx5lObbcOKpCYV5jTPPIU/muPBShmelb1x5dXnjxps0lSruvLex7bo/)

Comment: @ETHproductions I get it... for some reason I was overthinking it. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Bubblegum, 182 bytes

```
00000000: 05c1 4792 e330 1004 c07b bda2 de51 3779  ..G..0...{...Q7y
00000010: efbd 6e10 b7b5 4210 644f 8026 46bf 9fcc  ..n...B.dO.&F...
00000020: 8138 48ef 80a1 38cc a177 8cc4 d127 e414  .8H...8..w...'..
00000030: 0d63 716c a90d 9888 93e2 e398 8a53 ff6d  .cql.........S.m
00000040: b3b7 9889 334f 6fcc c5b9 b796 b010 17f5  ....3Oo.........
00000050: bf18 b014 975d 8ad6 6225 ae62 72ac c575  .....]..b%.br..u
00000060: ac02 36e2 2696 86ad b8f5 deaa 9765 ecc4  ..6.&........e..
00000070: 5d53 848c bdb8 0f3f 0107 f1d0 d9cb 0a1c  ]S.....?........
00000080: c5a3 57e6 3889 a768 3907 9cc5 73a8 ff3b  ..W.8..h9...s..;
00000090: 2ee2 a58e 6fcf 15ae e235 16ad 67dc c4db  ....o....5..g...
000000a0: 2736 a57d 7117 ef39 7cf1 101f a12e cdf0  '6.}q..9|.......
000000b0: 149f 5dea fe00                           ..]...
```

Just Zopfli'd the target string for 100 000 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 131 bytes

130 bytes +1 for the `-R` flag.

```
;B¬®+": "+`AlfaBŸvoC•r¦eDeltaE®oFoxÉ•GolfHÇUI˜iaJªietKiloL‹aMikeNovem¼rOs¯rPapaQue¼cRo´oSi€ŸTÂ
UnifŽmVÅ¡rW–skeyXŸyY„keeZªu`fZ+"%a+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#AaEAXv//O0LCrMKuKyI6ICIrYEFsZmFCwp92b0PClXLCpmVEZWx0YUXCrm9Gb3jDicKVR29sZkjDh1VJwphpYUrCqmlldEtpbG9MwothTWlrZU5vdmVtwrxyT3PCr3JQYXBhUXVlwrxjUm/CtG9TacKAwp9Uw4IKVW5pZsKObVbDhcKhclfClnNrZXlYwp95WcKEa2VlWsKqdWBmWisiJWEr//8tUg)

#### Explanation

```
;B¬®+": "+`{compressed string}`fZ+"%a+
;B                                     // Alphabet shortcut (ABC...XYZ)
  ¬                                    // Splits the Alphabet, by char, into new lines
   ®                                   // Shortcut for mZ{Z, which maps each item Z to the following:
    +": "+                             //   (Implicit) Z + ": " +
                               fZ+"%a+ //   matches of Z followed by lowercase letters, in
          `{compressed string}`        //   the compressed string "Alfa...Zulu". Backticks are used to decompress the string
```

The `-R`flag is used to seperate each item by newlines.

Japt uses the [shoco library](http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco/) for string compression.

Comment: Nice one! This reminds me of the original version of your answer on [Create an Alphabet Song](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109518/42545), unfortunately we can't use the same tricks here that we did there.

Answer (score 1):

## [Chipmunk BASIC](http://www.nicholson.com/rhn/basic.html), 191 characters

(Inspired by [anonymous2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59866/anonymous2)'s [QBasic solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112257). Was just too impatient to see a `data` based variant, so tried it myself.)

```basic
data lfa,ravo,harlie,elta,cho,oxtrot,olf,otel,ndia,uliet,ilo,ima,ike,ovember,scar,apa,uebec,omeo,ierra,ango,niform,ictor,hiskey,ray,ankee,ulu
for i=65to 90
read w$
?chr$(i)": "chr$(i)w$
next
```

Sample run:

```
Chipmunk BASIC v3.5.8b9
>load "nato.bas"
>run
A: Alfa
B: Bravo
C: Charlie
D: Delta
E: Echo
F: Foxtrot
G: Golf
H: Hotel
I: India
J: Juliet
K: Kilo
L: Lima
M: Mike
N: November
O: Oscar
P: Papa
Q: Quebec
R: Romeo
S: Sierra
T: Tango
U: Uniform
V: Victor
W: Whiskey
X: Xray
Y: Yankee
Z: Zulu
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 219 bytes

```
(dolist(c'(alfa bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliet kilo lima mike november oscar papa quebec romeo sierra tango uniform victor whiskey xray yankee zulu))(format t"~C: ~:(~A~)~%"(char(string c)0)c))
```

Ungolfed

```
(dolist (c '(alfa bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliet kilo lima mike november oscar papa quebec romeo sierra tango uniform victor whiskey xray yankee zulu)) 
  (format t "~C: ~:(~A~)~%" (char (string c) 0) c))
```

Explaination:

`dolist` is effectively the CL equivalent of python's for _ in _ loop.

The words themselves are stored as lisp symbols, which are upcased after parsing by default.

`format` actually handles printing out to screen. The heavily lifting is in the format control string: "~C: ~:(~A~)~%".

~C takes a char and just prints it, ~A does the same with an arbitrary lisp object. ~:( and ~) are 'case control' directives, which upcase the first letter of any word printed between them.

`(char (string c) 0)` Gets the string for the symbol c and pulls the first char out of it.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 191 bytes

Really nothing fancy, but it's Friday and I wanted to go golfing for the first time.

```
char c=65;"lfa ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu".split().any{println("${c}: ${c++}"+it)}​
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/groovy#DY1BCsJQDESvMhQXLQV3ulA8TPymNvT3p6RRLFJw7y29SM1mFjOPN1vqyZAux8O5yh3B6KmIKguDsxNSr9CXmzo0d1DnjHITwiMQh2SFjAQZGPrk8cqGOYWSpkD4ygk6cjBsRqByVxTp1EZIcjX0Mg@8xO0S48Ac2ke1n6csXjd7Kst7MimeS13t3mk9IbJt16oVb9bf57ttfw)

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

## 8086 machine code, 187 bytes

```
00000000  be 4c 01 31 c9 53 89 e5  68 0a 24 8a 8f 32 01 29  |.L.1.S..h.$..2.)|
00000010  cc 89 e7 f3 a4 83 c3 41  b7 20 86 fb 53 b3 3a 86  |.......A. ..S.:.|
00000020  fb 53 89 e2 b4 09 cd 21  89 ec 5b 43 83 fb 1a 75  |.S.....!..[C...u|
00000030  d4 c3 03 04 06 04 03 06  03 04 04 05 03 03 03 07  |................|
00000040  04 03 05 04 05 04 06 05  06 03 05 03 6c 66 61 72  |............lfar|
00000050  61 76 6f 68 61 72 6c 69  65 65 6c 74 61 63 68 6f  |avoharlieeltacho|
00000060  6f 78 74 72 6f 74 6f 6c  66 6f 74 65 6c 6e 64 69  |oxtrotolfotelndi|
00000070  61 75 6c 69 65 74 69 6c  6f 69 6d 61 69 6b 65 6f  |aulietiloimaikeo|
00000080  76 65 6d 62 65 72 73 63  61 72 61 70 61 75 65 62  |vemberscarapaueb|
00000090  65 63 6f 6d 65 6f 69 65  72 72 61 61 6e 67 6f 6e  |ecomeoierraangon|
000000a0  69 66 6f 72 6d 69 63 74  6f 72 68 69 73 6b 65 79  |iformictorhiskey|
000000b0  72 61 79 61 6e 6b 65 65  75 6c 75                 |rayankeeulu|
000000bb
```

Equivalent assembly code:

```
org 0x100
use16
    mov si, nato
    xor cx, cx
@@: push bx
    mov bp, sp
    push 0x240a
    mov cl, [len+bx]
    sub sp, cx
    mov di, sp
    rep movsb
    add bx, 'A'
    mov bh, ' '
    xchg bh, bl
    push bx
    mov bl, ':' 
    xchg bh, bl
    push bx
    mov dx, sp
    mov ah, 0x09
    int 0x21
    mov sp, bp
    pop bx
    inc bx
    cmp bx, 26
    jne @b
    ret

len db 3,4,6,4,3,6,3,4,4,5,3,3,3,7,4,3,5,4,5,4,6,5,6,3,5,3
nato db "lfaravoharlieeltachooxtrotolfotelndiaulietiloimaikeovemberscarapauebecomeoierraangoniformictorhiskeyrayankeeulu"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), <strike>78</strike> 76 bytes

```
m':ᵛ+"vD∦C∑:ḋᵉ∑7ðȮ÷m^¹,ṫ₈Cⁿ«⁾hƒu~Φ∑₈DᴳkƓᶤNGġṀ<ϩɠ←⁰øWᵘ₉Πȧƛ₄∦ιqṘᶴ]←Ṭ}₈NḋẠᵃ”ṂZ'
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJtJzrhtZsrXCJ2ROKIpkPiiJE64biL4bWJ4oiRN8OwyK7Dt21ewrks4bmr4oKIQ+KBv8Kr4oG+aMaSdX7OpuKIkeKCiEThtLNrxpPhtqROR8Sh4bmAPM+pyaDihpDigbDDuFfhtZjigonOoMinxpvigoTiiKbOuXHhuZjhtrRd4oaQ4bmsfeKCiE7huIvhuqDhtYPigJ3huYJaJyIsIiIsIiIsIjMuNC4xIl0=)

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 216 bytes

```
@for %%w in (Alfa Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel India Juliet Kilo Lima Mike November Oscar Papa Quebec Romeo Sierra Tango Uniform Victor Whiskey Xray Yankee Zulu)do @set l=%%w&call echo %%l:~,1%%: %%l%%
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>160</s> 158 bytes

```
'A"lfa ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu"S/{_": "\_)QN@}fQ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#Dc3BCsIwEIThVxlyEU/e9aIvIBSvQtnGjVmSdGWblhbx2WvO8zH/fri5HAhGiyKSZWFwrgQfFbpW0wrNAVo5Y3wJYW6kQrJCCkESQxcuAxsmTwb6NMIDe2jhZtiMQONbMUpQKxBf1RBlSry17NbGxNxuZ/c4fXt3hnv2x@5@/YXusu9/)

**Explanation**

```
'A                         Push the character 'A'
  "..."S/                  Split huge string on spaces
         {           }fQ   For each word Q:
          _                  Duplicate top of stack (the character)
           ": "\             Push ": ", swap top stack elements; results in "A: A"
                _)           Duplicate the char on top and increment it (the next letter)
                  QN         Push Q and a newline
                    @        Bring the third-top element of the stack to the top
                              (brings the next character on top for the next iteration)
                        ;  Delete the top stack element, since at the end there will be a
                            '[' character on top
```

Answer (score 0):

### IBM/Lotus Notes Formula - 195 Bytes

```
L:=@Explode("Alfa Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel India Juliet Kilo Lima Mike November Oscar Papa Quebec Romeo Sierra Tango Uniform Victor Whiskey Xray Yankee Zulu");@Left(L;1)+": "+L
```

Formula will by default apply a given function to each value in a list in turn so no `for` loop needed. `@Explode` (equivalent to `split` in other  more sensible languages) defaults to `" "`,`","` or `";"` if no separator is supplied in the function call. As an aside, `@Implode` also equates to `join`. I guess formula is a bit too verbose and was not really made for golfing but some of the list operators are still cool and work as well as they did 20 odd years ago.

No TIO available for LN so screenshot shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 393 bytes

```c
#define p printf
long a[]={0x16C,0xf7f13f,0x59c3f18,0x15fc5,0xF83,0x5f0f3f5f9f0f,0x6c0f,0xC55f0f,0x194e,0x5f59c6f,0xfc9,0x1d9,0x5b9,0x3f52d57f0f,0x3f134f,0x11f1,0x35256f,0xf5d0f,0x13f3f59,0xf7e1,0xd3f0f69e,0x3f0f5f39,0xafb4f98,0xaf13f,0x55be1,0x6fc6f};i,j;d(long n){for(;n;n/=16){if(j=n&15){if(j>14)n/=16,j+=n&15;p("%c",96+j);}else n=0;}}r(){for(i=0;i<26;p("\n"))p("%c: %1$c",i+65),d(a[i++]);}
```

I thought it would be shorter than it is. I was wrong..

Each `long int` in `long a[]` represents a word containing the remaining letters of the required mnemonic once the first letter has been removed. Letters are encoded right to left whereby if the 4 lower bits are `0xF` then it adds it to the next 4 bits and shifts it all down appropriately, repeating until the variable is empty.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#LVDLbsIwELzzFRYtla1EaoyzBtdNL0j9CcohxF7kiBqUUgkpyrfTtdOLZx8zs7t@PDmPIXp2ZdchxBsuzpd4Yu3@0IzVXepdWd1xg1IhBWA6hXJLkQTsgPBzq1IdK1QIaAgp1V2GHcCcS1P7zCK9TgXsTCq79MIxvaReO9jMfJqh6iyUKFMOa5h14GZDlcaZvJpPDKdIqY3P4oo2UanZ4rFGs83R/wFwzHyNtMhkQ9lbx/PBUYx4GbiNNr42UosxIO@b@CJhDj9kLXKn7Itctle@XHXL0uiiF3by5x/PYlPZaRr47BUoC@9rnZhfcSlEVryxlXwmXSg0iNLxdh@K4kAOD/p99t2GyAUbF4yRjU3gb79DZJVdTI8/)

Comment: 283: main(){puts("A: Alfa\nB: Bravo\nC: Charlie\nD: Delta\nE: Echo\nF: Foxtrot\nG: Golf\nH: Hotel\nI: India\nJ: Juliet\nK: Kilo\nL: Lima\nM: Mike\nN: November\nO: Oscar\nP: Papa\nQ: Quebec\nR: Romeo\nS: Sierra\nT: Tango\nU: Uniform\nV: Victor\nW: Whiskey\nX: Xray\nY: Yankee\nZ: Zulu");}

Comment: @jayjay kind of takes the fun out of it, doesn't it?

Comment: I will give you that! Yours is much more interesting. :)

Comment: [352 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY/LTsMwEEX3fEUUaGUrg@rH2M40hC74jNJFSOIqEbhRxQIp6reXcVdj37nnWO5fz31/vz8PY5zSWCzFcp3SbxRP35d0LrrjqV2tR1B/MURtIxBq42qsgZRyFiwFzUsXVbTRReIJJnhvOfxwOQaPgdtEtUEMgAo1YLCg0TsuMWUGF3IRtbVB89YRi7E2RNkd3ZCliowxSoO36ALHg2XG0/hwKH7bEh@7@IWRagiaTQTW6cwwUVu6NXMziMe/klzTdjsIMbdpq508zFU7v2s8pF2rPeRsr2ApN30J5KtZQtppv1eyuV3FJNd44dGqZnozvlnKz1RKmdv7YqNfmJkq7yQMojtOVXVi6v7TTUnI9Sry5R8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## C, 199 bytes

```
f(){char*s=" AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu";while(*++s){printf("\n%c: %c"+*s/96*5,*s,*s);}}
```

Comment: I've been banging my head on this: `"\n%c: %c"+*s/96*5` and I can't understand why it works. Care to elaborate? Also isn't it possible to remove the new line in the front? With it the solution is not correct.

Comment: BTW, your solution could be rewritten with a `for` loop and the `printf` could be changed to `printf("\n%c: %1$c"+*s/96*5,*s)` and thus save 4 bytes. Though it's still not correct.

Comment: And please, explain how this works: `"\n%c: %c"+*s/96*5`.

Comment: @ItayGrudev I’ll look into a fix later. `"abc"` is a pointer to the start of a constant string, and `"abc"+2` adds `2` to that pointer, giving you a pointer to `"c"`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 188 bytes

```
$n=64;$x="LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUlietIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu";while($x=~/.[a-z]*/g){$_=chr(++$n)."\l$&
";s/(.).*/$1: $&/;print}
```

Ungolfed version:

```perl
$x="LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUlietIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu";
$n=64;
while ($x =~ /([A-Z][a-z]*)/g) {
    $y = chr(++$n) . "\l$1\n";
    $y =~ s/(.)(.*)/$1: $1$2/;
    print $y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, <strike>185</strike> <strike>164</strike> 163 bytes

Saved <strike>11</strike> 12 bytes with help from @manatwork

```
print$a=chr$i+++65,": $a\l$_\n"for split/(?=[A-Z])/,LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUlietIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu
```

Comment: May I suggest to reorder the used instructions/functions? `print$a=chr$i+++65,": $a\l$_\n"for split/(?=[A-Z])/,LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUlietIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu`

Comment: Nice! thanks, I'll update my code

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 192 bytes

```
@='lpha ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu'
do #=1 to 26
  c=d2c(#+64)
  say c':' c||word(@,#)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, <s>300</s> 275 bytes

```
interface x{static void main(String[]a){for(int i=0;i<26;i++) System.out.println(String.format("%c: %c%s",'A'+i,'A'+i,"lfa_ravo_harlie_elta_cho_oxtrot_olf_otel_ndia_uliet_ilo_ima_ike_ovember_scar_apa_uebec_omeo_ierra_ango_niform_ictor_hiskey_ray_ankee_ulu".split("_")[i]));}}
```

Ungolfed version with comments:

```
interface x {
    static void main(String[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)            // For all characters in alphabet
            System.out.println(                 // Print string
                    String.format("%c: %c%s",   // Formatted string(similar to printf)
                            'A'+i,              // Letter
                            'A'+i,              // Letter
                            "lfa_ravo_harlie_elta_cho_oxtrot_olf_otel_ndia_uliet_ilo_ima_ike_ovember_scar_apa_uebec_omeo_ierra_ango_niform_ictor_hiskey_ray_ankee_ulu".split("_")[i])); // Absurdly long string containing all words without first letters, divided into an array by _
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## q, 167 bytes

[Link](https://kx.com/download/) to interpreter download

```
-1@.Q.A,'": ",/:.Q.A,'" "vs"lpha ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliet ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu";
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 108 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I suspect there may be another byte or 2 to be saved here, possibly by interleaving with the uppercase alphabet, but I'm running out the door so it'll have to do for now.

Note the trailing space.

```
`lfaæ1ÃÉr¦e³ltawÖoxÉwolfÙ*lÙAawªià5¹µ±kewovem¼rws¯r°pawue¼cÙ o±ØÇ¯fmØtØkeyÙ°nkeewªu`qÔËi°Id ²i1":
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=YGxmYeYxw8lypmWzbHRhd9aeb3jJlXdvbGbZKmzZQWF3qmngNY25tbFrZXdvdmVtvHJ3c69ysHBhd3VlvGPZIG%2bxgJ/YAcevZo5t2HSO2JFrZXnZn7Bua2Vld6p1YHHUy2mwSWQgsmkxIjog)

```
`...`qÔËi°Id ²i1": 
`...`                   :Compressed string "lfawravowharlieweltawchowoxtrotwolfwotelwndiawulietwilowimawikewovemberwscarwapawuebecwomeowierrawangowniformwictorwhiskeywraywankeewulu"
     q                  :Split on
      Ô                 :  "w"
       Ë                :Map
        i               :  Prepend
         °I             :    Prefix increment I, initially 64
           d            :    Get character at that codepoint
             ²          :    Repeat twice
              i1":      :    Insert ": " at 0-based index 1
                        :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 81 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
’lfaŒ¥ȷþ<ƭ`Ṃ⁸Ø⁽ÄƝḲƲḤJulietƒḍɲḄẠ[Ḷ⁸Ọ¦ṢĖḞɠṘ»oẹ⁽ẓẇṅ⁼ṡ÷ẏƬ»|»⁸“¶’"[A-Z]"ḄkAZıẸD`: +ƤJƤ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kp9S7IKlpSVpuhY3FzxqmJmTlnh00qGlJ7Yf3mdzbG3Cw51Njxp3HJ7xqHHv4ZZjcx_u2HRs08MdS7xKczJTS45Nerij9ySQ3_Jw14Lohzu2AZU-3N1zaNnDnYuOTHu4Y97JBQ93zji0O__hrp1AAx7umvxwV_vDna2PGvc83Lnw8PaHu_qPrTm0u-bQbqDGRw1zDm0DOkAp2lE3KlYJaGi2Y9SRjQ937XBJsFLQPrbE69iSJcVJycVQ1y6A0gA)

##### Explanation

```python
’...’"[A-Z]"ḄkAZıẸD`: +ƤJƤ  # Full program
’...’                       # Push compressed string "lfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJulietKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu"
     "[A-Z]"Ḅ               # Split on uppercase letters
             kAZ            # Zip with the uppercase alphabet
                ı           # Map over this list of pairs:
                 ẸD         #  Dump onto stack and duplicate the letter
                   `: +     #  Append ": " to one copy
                       Ƥ    #  Prepend this to the other copy
                        JƤ  #  Join and prepend this to the string
                            # Implicit output, joined on newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, <s>132</s> 124 bytes

```
_.": "._MAZ.:J(zA*":yE-HFZ[`\0,A-%[z5/gh4!R
c}FNu3GM%uHk{yKs.B/OVMKb XP14DXDT[Em%
.rUog"FD126TD25)^'w
```

The code contains unprintable characters which do not display correctly on StackExchange. Here's a hexdump:

```
00000000: 5f2e 223a 2022 2e5f 4d41 5a2e 3a4a 287a  _.": "._MAZ.:J(z
00000010: 412a 2205 3a79 452d 4812 465a 5b60 1b5c  A*".:yE-H.FZ[`.\
00000020: 3006 2c41 2d25 5b7a 352f 6768 1008 1334  0.,A-%[z5/gh...4
00000030: 2152 1215 0a63 7d46 4e75 3305 474d 2575  !R...c}FNu3.GM%u
00000040: 1048 6b7b 794b 732e 1c42 2f4f 5619 4d07  .Hk{yKs..B/OV.M.
00000050: 074b 6220 5850 1131 3444 5844 545b 456d  .Kb XP.14DXDT[Em
00000060: 250a 191b 172e 1b72 0117 5517 6f67 2246  %......r..U.og"F
00000070: 4431 3236 5444 3235 295e 2777            D126TD25)^'w
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbo5S7IKlpSVpuhY3a-L1lKwUlPTifR2j9Ky8NKoctZRYrSpddT2E3KKiE6RjDNh0HHVVo6tM9dMzBDiETRSDhES5kmvd_EqNWd19VUsFPLKrK72L9WSc9P3DJH3Z2b2TFCICBA1NXCJcQqJdc1W5JKXF9aSLGMVDxfPTldxcDI3MQlyMTDXj1MshboA6ZQGUBgA)

#### Explanation

Similar compression approach to [another recent kolmo answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269482/16766):

```
_.": "._MAZ.:J(zA*"..."FD126TD25)^'w
                  "..."               String of characters
                A*                    Get ASCII code of each
                       FD126          Treat those as base-126 digits and convert
                                      to base 10
                            TD25      Convert to list of base-25 digits
              (z                )     Index into lowercase alphabet
             J                        Join into a single string
                                 ^'w  Split on w's
                                      This gives a list ["lpha";"ravo";...;"ulu"]
         AZ                           Uppercase alphabet
        M                             Map this function to each letter:
_                                      The letter
 .": "                                 Concatenate colon-space
      ._                               Concatenate the letter again
           .:                         Concatenate that list itemwise with the list
                                      from earlier
                                      Print each on a separate line (-l flag)
```

Base 126 was chosen to avoid having any `"` characters in the string.