# Write a function/method that takes in a string and spells that word out using the NATO Phonetic Alphabet. Titlecase optional

Tags: code-golf, string, alphabet

Write a program that takes in a string and spells that word out using the NATO Phonetic Alphabet.

The mapping is as follows:

```
'A' -> 'Alfa'
'B' -> 'Bravo'
'C' -> 'Charlie'
'D' -> 'Delta'
'E' -> 'Echo'
'F' -> 'Foxtrot'
'G' -> 'Golf'
'H' -> 'Hotel'
'I' -> 'India'
'J' -> 'Juliett'
'K' -> 'Kilo'
'L' -> 'Lima'
'M' -> 'Mike'
'N' -> 'November'
'O' -> 'Oscar'
'P' -> 'Papa'
'Q' -> 'Quebec'
'R' -> 'Romeo'
'S' -> 'Sierra'
'T' -> 'Tango'
'U' -> 'Uniform'
'V' -> 'Victor'
'W' -> 'Whiskey'
'X' -> 'Xray'
'Y' -> 'Yankee'
'Z' -> 'Zulu'
```

Example:

`'Hello World' -> ['Hotel', 'Echo', 'Lima', 'Lima', 'Oscar', 'Whiskey', 'Oscar', 'Romeo', 'Lima', 'Delta']`

The input can be any string, but will always be comprised of only letters and spaces. Case is irrelevant in the output, but the input may contain letters in uppercase, lowercase, or both. Spaces should be ignored in the output.

You can output in any reasonable format, but it must be a delimited set of NATO callsigns.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This question has already been asked. But it probably would have been closed anyway for several other reasons: 1) Unless there's a good reason to do so, asking to answer in a specific way (a function) in a specific language is usually frowned upon. 2) Challenges must be self-contained: you should explain what the NATO phonetic alphabet exactly is within the body of the question. 3) In its current form, it looks like a homework assignment. If it is, you might find help on Stack Overflow, provided that you include what you've done so far and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: I'd be in favour of reopening this if the points @Arnauld raised above were addressed as it doesn't have the source restriction or input validation of the linked challenge.

Comment: @JoKing, from the test case, which includes a space, it looks like they're simply stripped.

Comment: I've edited this to possibly be re-openable, since it doesn't have the restriction on characters. Are all my changes appropriate? Especially check the input restrictions.

Comment: @Riker, personally, I'd say ditch the `-` in `X-ray` and require the output be in title case.

Comment: I agree with @Shaggy about ditching the `-` in `X-ray`. Whether the output must be titlecase or not I personally don't mind either.

Comment: @Shaggy I'll leave that up to OP. I had the - in since I copied that from a list of NATO callsigns and I haven't voted to reopen yet. OP can decide the rest.

Comment: This is the ICAO alphabet; the NATO alphabet uses `Alpha` and `Juliet` instead.

Comment: Can we optionally have the `-` in X-ray?

Comment: `Whisky` in the example is not equals to `Whiskey` in the mapping.

Answer (score 13):

## [sfk](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html), <s>78</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```
+filt
+spell -nato
+xed _ph_f_ _et_ett_ _-__ "*: [keep]""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K07L/v9fOy0zp4RLu7ggNSdHQTcvsSSfS7siNUUhviAjPi1eIT61BIhKgAzd@HgFJS0rhejs1NSCWCWl//89gFryFcLzi3JSEgE)

Just use the right tool.

Output is the phonetics separated by one or more spaces.

Answer (score 6):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, 192 bytes

```
be80 00ad 8ac8 ac51 24df 8ad0 2c40 3c1b 7321 8af0 b024 b18b 9090 bf37 01f2 aefe
ce75 fab4 02cd 218b d7b4 09cd 21b2 20b4 02cd 2159 e2d0 c324 6c66 6124 7261 766f
2468 6172 6c69 6524 656c 7461 2463 686f 246f 7874 726f 7424 6f6c 6624 6f74 656c
246e 6469 6124 756c 6965 7474 2469 6c6f 2469 6d61 2469 6b65 246f 7665 6d62 6572
2473 6361 7224 6170 6124 7565 6265 6324 6f6d 656f 2469 6572 7261 2461 6e67 6f24
6e69 666f 726d 2469 6374 6f72 2468 6973 6b65 7924 7261 7924 616e 6b65 6524 756c
7524

    MOV  SI, 80H            ; point SI to DOS PSP
    LODSW                   ; load arg length into AL, advance SI to 82H
    MOV  CL, AL             ; set up loop counter
SEARCH:
    LODSB                   ; load next char from DS:SI into AL, advance SI 
    PUSH CX                 ; save outer loop position
    AND  AL, 0DFH           ; uppercase the input letter
    MOV  DL, AL             ; save for output
    SUB  AL, 'A'-1          ; convert letter to one-based index (A=1, Z=26, etc)
    CMP  AL, 27             ; if greater than 26, not a valid char
    JNC  NOTFOUND           ; if not, move to next
    MOV  DH, AL             ; DH is loop counter
    MOV  AL, '$'            ; search for string delimiter
    MOV  CL, LNATO          ; repeat search through length of word data
    MOV  DI, OFFSET NATO    ; re-point SCASB to beginning of word data
SCANLOOP:
    REPNZ SCASB             ; search until delimiter in AL is found ES:DI, advance DI
    DEC  DH                 ; delimiter found, decrement counter
    JNZ  SCANLOOP           ; if counter reached 0, index has been found
    MOV  AH, 02H            ; display first char
    INT  21H
    MOV  DX, DI             ; put found string memory location to DX for display
    MOV  AH, 09H            ; display string function
    INT  21H
    MOV  DL, ' '            ; display a space between words
    MOV  AH, 02H
    INT  21H
NOTFOUND:
    POP  CX                 ; restore outer loop counter
    LOOP SEARCH             ; move to next char in input
    RET
NATO    DB  '$lfa$ravo$harlie$elta$cho$oxtrot$olf$otel$ndia$'
        DB  'uliett$ilo$ima$ike$ovember$scar$apa$uebec$omeo$'
        DB  'ierra$ango$niform$ictor$hiskey$ray$ankee$ulu$'
LNATO   EQU $-NATO
```

Test output:

```
A>NATO abc aaa
Alfa Bravo Charlie Alfa Alfa Alfa 
A>NATO abc DefG1HIJ
Alfa Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel India Juliett 
A>NATO Alfa Bravo!
Alfa Lima Foxtrot Alfa Bravo Romeo Alfa Victor Oscar
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by figuring out how to turn off the NOP padding, or using a different version that doesn't do it. I used ML.EXE and it does not do the padding. You can save another 18 bytes or so by removing the `$` delimiters and separating the words by capitalizing their first letter instead (and by first I mean second, because you already left out the first). (A higher level of compression could probably be reached before the length of code needed to decompress it would outweigh the advantage of the compression, but the simple scheme of capital-letter-delimiters would be a good start.)

Comment: Using MASM 5, I've tried all variations of ALIGN and EVEN, and moving instructions around and no matter what it really likes to pad before the REPNZ.  The $ delimiter was a cheap way to have both an array delimited and a string delimiter so I could use INT 21H:09 and not have to write a loop structure to print it char by char.  I like your idea about using capitals as delimiters, something like 'LfaRavoHarlie' , yes? Per the spec, case is irrelevant so outputting ALfa or CHarlie would be perfectly acceptable. Great ideas! Will need to code it up and see what the size diff end up being.

Comment: Apparently MASM 9 was the last version that had an /AT option (for .MODEL TINY), and in my test with your code it did not do the NOP padding. The `ML.EXE /?` output says `Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 9.00.30729.01`. Yep, 'LfaRavoHarlie' is exactly what I meant. :) I would do the "OR AL, 20H" to make it lowercase again in the output, but it's up to you.

Comment: BTW, why not include the header and footer in your unassembled view? MASM 9 wouldn't compile it for me without that. I mean the `.MODEL TINY` `.CODE` `ORG 100H` `START:` at the beginning and `END START` at the end. Did you not need this to compile it with MASM 5?

Comment: I don't typically include the MASM boilerplate because it's not part of the assembled code (you can get to the same byte code multiple ways depending on your version of MASM and all). I use the "old" syntax because I like to test it on MASM 1.1. :)  I believe I've found the NOP issue and it's likely a MASM bug that existed at least between 1.1 and 5. If you place the LNATO EQU above the code or hard code 08BH in place, it does not insert the two NOPs. However since the LNATO EQU is below the code, there's a difference in what it does between pass1 and pass2, leaving that space there. Bizarre!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88858/discussion-between-gwaugh-and-deadcode).

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>102</s> <s>96</s> 95 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
álSA”AlfaÐ†vo¼¯¤œ®È¨›trotŠˆƒ‹Š™ÈŸtt Kilo´àma—……ÍÐ—Žêpa¼°«Äoµ†Çâgo¸šÉµ Whiskey Xrayµ‹nkeeâ¸lu”#‡
```

Output is a list of Titlecased NATO words.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##Fc6xCsIwFIXhVwn4JN0ER4e6RoxaGo20VeiWoWgdBNGuQlpEREEdLLSiy73ExbfIi9QWzvbDxxE@7TusqjDlXcvIg8WHFLdGqoWAN9zhqPdwwxjORr4CTwRa/ZbfnZGlVibKMNZFEJCOwwU8UU2okYmRp3q4aZREf/Ayo7X0gCtGAvJaxhVmIwGFTnENObHHju@ykPQ8Gja9nLqMYQYFn9d/WkamVdVmnAtiC48P/g)

**Explanation:**

```python
á              # Only leave the letters of the (implicit) input
 l             # Convert it to lowercase
  S            # Split it to a list of characters
   A           # Push the alphabet
    ”...”      # Push all the NATO words in titlecase and space-delimited
         #     # Split the string by spaces
          ‡    # Transliterate; map all letters in the lowercase input with this
               # list at the same indices (and output the resulting list implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `”AlfaÐ†vo¼¯¤œ®È¨›trotŠˆƒ‹Š™ÈŸtt Kilo´àma—……ÍÐ—Žêpa¼°«Äoµ†Çâgo¸šÉµ Whiskey Xrayµ‹nkeeâ¸lu”` is `"Alfa Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel India Juliett Kilo Lima Mike November Oscar Papa Quebec Romeo Sierra Tango Uniform Victor Whiskey Xray Yankee Zulu"`. Credit of this compressed dictionary string goes to [*@ErikTheGolfer* in this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/112208/charlie-oscar-delta-echo?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment273386_112221) (with an added `t` for `Juliett` instead of `Juliet`).

Comment: May be able to use interpolation, and compression to lower the byte-count of the non-existant words (trot, tt Kilo, Whiskey Xray). Halfassed example: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AcUAOv9vc2FiaWX//8OhbFNBLuKAokFBT8O4wqfDr27DrM6pRDRcwqHDvcO3y5zigKInesKhUmDigJ1BbGZhw5DigKB2b8K8wq/CpMWTwq7DiMKo4oC6w7/FoMuGxpLigLnFoOKEosOIxbjDv8K0w6BtYeKAlOKApuKApsONw5DigJTFvcOqcGHCvMKwwqvDhG/CteKAoMOHw6Jnb8K4xaHDicK1w7/CteKAuW5rZWXDosK4bHXigJ0j4oCh//9IZWxsbyBXb3JsZA "05AB1E – Try It Online") I've done it before, but it was for a LARGE amount of words, in this it'd save at best 1 byte if you spent time.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>80</s>  77 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḟ⁶O%32ị“¡µQỤ(cɠṘwlṁ;Ɗœ<NẸ½ṗN¬ṙẋxḶb¤*O~Æƒ¹.ß8Ḋ¡tJ|Ḷ<İİḂ^1eȷjċbY9TYƭ¹Ẉ¥¤K0¹f»Ḳ¤
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AZ8AYP9qZWxsef//4bif4oG2TyUzMuG7i@KAnMKhwrVR4bukKGPJoOG5mHds4bmBO8aKxZM8TuG6uMK94bmXTsKs4bmZ4bqLeOG4tmLCpCpPfsOGxpLCuS7DnzjhuIrCoXRKfOG4tjzEsMSw4biCXjFlyLdqxItiWTlUWcatwrnhuojCpcKkSzDCuWbCu@G4ssKk/8OHS///SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ)** (The footer formats the list by joining with spaces to avoid implicit smashing print when run as a full program)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>181</s> 189 bytes

```
s=>s.match(/\w/g).map(c=>'IndiAlfABravOscaRomeOQuebeCharliEchODeltAGolFoxtroTangOHoteLimAJulietTKilOZulUniforMikENovembeRPapASierrAVictoRWhiskeYankeEXraY'.match(c.toUpperCase()+'.*?[A-Z]'))
```

Since output case doesn't matter, we can save bytes by running words together:

```
... GolFoxtroTangO ...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NToNAFEb3PgW7AZvSBzCtGStaf1Haqq26GIYLTLnMxZkBqi@PXRhjXJ7kO1/OTnTCSqMaN9aUwYDgvHw62OnMhrVwsvQnb/2kCA7Q@HI6Y1c6UxxzfmZEF1spEqohfmwhhXkpDKpIlvE5oOOXhBe0d4ZWQhfxghzcqppft6jArW4UxtsW11rlZO5UFd1TB3UKyYNo@FKBMfxJSUfJc6lsBRuhK4hejNiwnyoZOlo3DZi5sOAHIxYen77y8fadBcEgSVtCCJEKP/fZAhDJ68lgxgJv5DEWnBz93fzDgyJSmUFelGpXYa2p@TDWtV2///z6fRi@AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 218 bytes

```cs
n=>n.ToUpper().Select(x=>"AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJuliettKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu".SkipWhile(k=>x!=k).TakeWhile((k,l)=>l<1|k>96&k<123))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBfT8JAEMS/ivbBXJPaBE1MDO0liiCg4h9A1LflWOBy29tmeyWQ@N1rE3xgniYzv5cZU12ayjaD2pusCmL9Jhn1fV2gwJIwO/VmC6K1hrzxufbpjOdliaLidIqEJqh9rqM7WsO9wI57LUwWH5AC9M2WB7wPwuGRaT3kgDTyKwvjukVCeLLEz7aAF@twwjssliivlQF5gxLea1yi@eACeWpRBGbgNzz3ds1SfFoTWBZbWzk8fAkcvsE7xJ@a6iidOlu2FaFyud6f5y5OZ@DwGCmXUJxryjq/Tt/eXLisc3Udx013ITagOl6Rjtl6FSVRAioaIhGfLVhoFZ1u/kd77A20Qdyq2/wB)

## Alternate version using Split(), 194 bytes

```cs
n=>n.ToUpper().Select(x=>x>64?x+"lfa,ravo,harlie,elta,cho,oxtrot,olf,otel,ndia,uliett,ilo,ima,ike,ovember,scar,apa,uebec,omeo,ierra,ango,niform,ictor,hiskey,ray,ankee,ulu".Split(',')[x%65]:x+"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY8xT8NADIX/CjoJ9SJMJuhAm@uAQMBaUAfE4FydxsrlHDmXKv314SQY6smyv@fn58d7P/LyOkW/HZNyPMH7S5x6UqwDba9736I657BaYuVi@Slfw0Bqi3JPgXyyc@Vmt37YzXcmNAiKZ4EsCUxAISH4VkDmpJJAQgOSKEA8MsKUkZSAgwD3CNwRyJn6mhRGjwo4ZIZq8iA9ZYZUETCeBCI3oj2wT6LQ8tjRJfte8rIjyncnU@6HwMmuYFV8z7frx5@n/J4pls1BOZH9i1x@CEdrwABa80YhyM1BNBzNdbZ/9Fmixzwocm2WXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>176 170</s> 166 bytes

```perl6
*.comb>>.&{$_~:128[q`>$RbD[Orlo~Q1nX,OVq8x9'6%h'1.I$83ua7	vsD=s-{W}{>iQ:Js37py)hNN,i{Pt\~#f4<>`.ords].base(35).split('J')[.ord%32]}.words
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0svOT83yc5OT61aJb7OytDIIrowgZHBTiWIJUnIpV6QL9q/KCe/LpDJMC9CSsc/rNCiwlKd2Uw1Q91Qz5NfxcKYvzTRnLNMsthFlNlWrFi3Ory22k4kM1DcSsCrvljGmFHKvKBSk1Euw89PJ1O4OqAkpk45jZ/dhMnGLkEvvyilOFYvKbE4VcPYVFOvuCAns0RD3UtdMxokpWpsFFurVw5S9N@aqzixUiFNQ8kjNScnXyE8vygnRUlTzyezuESvAOgj6/8A)

Outputs in uppercases with the first letter in the original case. Compresses the string, which only saves 6 bytes over the simpler plain text:

```perl6
*.comb>>.&{$_~ <lfa ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliett ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu>[.ord%32-1]if ' 'ne$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc/NasNADATge59iCPlrIYa20EtSn/sGPYQS5LW2Ft61jLwJNaF9dVfn@ZhhRrb0tuQZ24h3LE9V0NzUdbW9ry9/OKVIMLopOrIkDE6FEDqF/hTTAk0RWjhhaIVwdVIKJCkkE6Rn6I1zw4YpkIFGN9xwgGZ2w2YEGr4Vg0S1DAlFDZ1MPc@@O3vYM3vvtT5Xau3m9eXw/CURO@wGXl9@l@PD5CzuVx@cfPZTLbWrx2r0W8flHw)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
*.comb>>.&{                 }         # Map each letter to
           $_~                        # The letter plus
              <...>[.ord%32]          # The letter indexed into the list of words
                             .words   # And remove the extra spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>250</s> 191 bytes

-47 bytes thanks to @Jo King, -2 more thanks to @Jonathan Allen

It goes through all non-space characters of the input, and for each of them it selects the relevant phrase for the letter, which can be reduced a bit because the first letter of each phrase is the character itself. Splits a string instead of storing the phrases as an array to save bytes from the unnecessary `'`s and `,`s.

```python
lambda s:[c+"lfa ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliett ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu".split()[ord(c)%32-1]for c in s if' '<c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY9NTsNADIWv8hQJNRECCbpDsOcOpQtn4iFWnHHkcQs5fZgF6/e9v22P2cr5KBQmef/4OpTWcSLUt0t67DQTnO6GmVyFwRqENBvsN9wCphkWrCiTEG4NiYCoQVaCLAy78zqyoyZy0NYYHjnBVm4MuxOofBuKZPMVksIcs9SF99a7N3Fhbrm37rluKtEPF/OpT8PD@fXp5dpMSJCCCsknnN7T9dhcSvT/f/ruk7XN@THXqRuG4w8)

Original solution

```python
lambda s:[c+['lfa','ravo','harlie','elta','cho','oxtrot','olf','otel','ndia','uliett','ilo','ima','ike','ovember','scar','apa','uebec','omeo','ierra','ango','niform','ictor','hiskey','ray','ankee','ulu'][ord(c)-65]for c in s.replace(" ", "").upper()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZBBbsUgDESvgtgE1N@/qdpFpe57hzQLhzgNioORQ36b06cYdcMM43mAyGdZOL1cCQrH@fz4ugi2cQKzv/fhqe9ohu7WCTy4ygJCEatBKhqHRVP@LcJFDc26FqQqaYpaOSpQdBhJu3HTMK56CD9wG1Gq2wOoQG4Ejhh0vGEjUERjSN@6TXFm2TQPhRVa4r7i2d54ttqK2O49uqFnmVzwz2@vQ6VMMDGZ/S6YCQI6a@zNWOvvR84ozg9XlpiK@/8KZz@RiM0PC03W@@sP)

Comment: 191 with `if' '<c`

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>210</s> 193 bytes

```
func[s][foreach c trim/all s[prin c print pick[:lfa:ravo:harlie:elta:cho:oxtrot:olf:otel:ndia:uliett:ilo:ima:ike:ovember:scar:apa:uebec:omeo:ierra:ango:niform:ictor:hiskey:ray:ankee:ulu]c% 32]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY6xbsQwDEP3foVxQOcC7cYv6Nylg@FBp8iNENkKFOfQ@/rUnQiQDyRDlutLllxeKtJVz875KLl6CPGaOI3Q9kZm6ch7aJ/Ov4y0K28ZVglBD8dKYSoQGwReHf47wgfcKnyIoS9KOCcyBtQc2gi6Cfwh7S6BgylA@2TkLgxvMhmJIFD/cXSdjxqUhwdWPTZ5zt3nDDeR2XsWfk0f76VcNd0@xczTt4ctt@sP)

### Explanation:

`foreach` iterates over the string after all whitespaces are removed by `trim/all`. `prin` prints the character (no newline). `print` prints a symbol, `pick`ed from the list of get-word!s (symbols) using the character mapped to the range 1..26 as an index.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 99 bytes

```
ＥΦ↥Ｓ№αι⁺ι§⪪”&⌊%w⁸D⦃σν:…ⅈ$|@Ｈ¦χＴ⸿]ECrΣＭ^¿←←&⁵↘⁼s(ＪＦ8X´▷⧴⎚Ｐ0V÷AＷχπ¶⌈≧\"dＪ^ZU{M≔⁴｜<¶⁹Ｂ⊞⊟1ＬPH⪪∨Y3`”j⌕αι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc5BasNADAXQfU9hvJqAe4KuSiA0i0IglK6VsRxLlkeDLJvk9I4K1U7oof/zCJYVZN8vRsXTN9R0InG09FMrWoYF07nU1a8e4J4Oh6456hoUuob@tousS6Ku@fRz6fGRrlXIUysDsMGmHAlCyCgOnEdlfbips8rA6ihcegJeg7gziTLNwDQh64bzDY2XDMZQw@ANM@uMYdAMGMpdudCgNjNlV@ORlgmfkfuM44QYf9e2a1puo@iJSv/fOuZj379QRJtfNenf9vdNXg) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs in proper case. Explanation:

```
   Ｓ                    Input string
  ↥                     Uppercased
 Φ                      Filtered where
     α                  Predefined uppercase alphabet
    №                   Contains
      ι                 Current character
Ｅ                       Mapped over characters
        ι               Current character
       ⁺                Concatenated with
           ”...”        Compressed string
          ⪪             Split on
                j       Literal string `j`
         §              Indexed by
                 ⌕      Index of
                   ι    Current character
                  α     In uppercase alphabet
                        Implicitly print each word on its own line
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 218 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$s=[takeWhile((<=)c)(dropWhile((<)c)['ZuluYankeeXrayWhiskeyVictorUniformTangoSierraRomeoQuebecPapaOscarNovemberMikeLimaKiloJuliettIndiaHotelGolfFoxtrotEchoDeltaCharlieBravoAlfa'])\\c<-map toUpper s|c>' ']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY9RT8JAEITf/RX3QNLywD8AExUUFBVFRC08LNctXLp3e9luG5v42601xmReZr55mLGEEDrPeU1oPLjQOR9Z1Kw1n4XmbFBNMoUStydHmKbjydAO01w4/ge9z5KPmup3CCXim0Dbo6rE9tVZZdkEV7D4FwhHXjsUgWf2yE81HtCuIMJjZUEeuEF/QLl3JS6dhztHfFuTQ9VFyB3MWZFumIpr/lRhndkTT5EUrk4gfe1SoOELKiDZD3c7Ox55iEZ5EyOKqb7seWKSfbdW6J9NzMBkyRyJ2GxZKO/Jty0IjlU3Wiy7aRvAO/tnVgT6u78bUa8qQIztDw)

Answer (score 2):

## C++, <s>229</s> 228 bytes

```
[](auto s){for(;auto t=*s?"LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUliettIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu":0;s++)if(int c=*s&31){for(cout<<*s;*t>96||--c;t++);for(;cout<<*t,*++t>96;);cout<<' ';}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBfa9swFMXf/SnuOljtpBkdg8ImNyOMQT1KDd3yNMa4lq8dzbLkSVf50zafPZOTQB/0cM/v6OroyGGYtVIe3iojdagJcmU9O8J@ngSvTAsGe/IDSgLPtUhejdEW@TxRhqFHZdIseU4ATjIoMwQWca6s1dAo5/mWXaBR2qyUJkhbYq0MpVKZq5M/yyIdlwCoBtI3x2sZSBsY8hzI1FqcdzWoPYnDr98pBrbgs@fGulQcB76d@C8X9w0@4treodOKvmnGrytbbtlZLnVTMumHWuEyMuZC26LHoqNyTX1F7odEtxhwSRXJsidbkHO4MK19UPGVvpBs3Z3yHe0ecbcwHdFSh4vP18JPp5lq0rESGUO8@/jhlGv8QZ5PvJjw/NPNy8tsJgVHrziGPlO@mkynIxfZWbqES7HfH8Y@0mNB7@Wf2G@aZWON@3gccXAGrkWyP/xcEfwLSnZQObsx0Ngt/A39QDXYNTngyDU@7aC2bfIdZVfjxoOODPodVKoFP6yU2YJt4h50/PQf)

Ungolfed:

```
[](const char *s)
{
    const char *table = "LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUliettIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu";
    for (; *s; s++)
    {
        char c = *s & 0x1F;
        if (c != 0)
        {
            cout << *s;
            const char *w = table;
            while (*w >= 'a' || --c)
                w++;
            do
                cout << *w;
            while (*++w >= 'a');
            cout << ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TAngo hOtel eCho qUebec uNiform iNdia cHarlie kIlo bRavo rOmeo oScar wHiskey nOvember fOxtrot oScar xRay jUliett uNiform mIke pApa eCho dElta oScar vIctor eCho rOmeo tAngo hOtel eCho lIma aLfa zUlu yAnkee dElta oScar gOlf 
JUliett aLfa cHarlie kIlo dElta aLfa wHiskey sIerra lIma oScar vIctor eCho mIke yAnkee bRavo iNdia gOlf sIerra pApa hOtel iNdia nOvember xRay oScar fOxtrot qUebec uNiform aLfa rOmeo tAngo zUlu
```

Clean-capitalization version (**234 bytes**):

```
[](auto s){for(;auto t=*s?"LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUliettIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu":0;s++)if(int c=*s&31){for(cout<<*s;*t>96||--c;t++);for(;putchar(*t|32),*++t>96;);cout<<' ';}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVBdb9NAEHz3r1iKRG2nQYVKSHBuUISQaoRqqTRPCKH1eW0fPt@Zu3U@2uS3h3NSiYd92J3Z2dmRwzBvpDy@VkbqsSLIlPXsCPtFNHplGjDYkx9QEniuRPSfGGgBX0TKMPSoTJxEzxHAeQzKDCOL0JfWaqiV83zLbqRptGmVJogbYq0MxVKZqzM/SQI6iQCoGuJXp7UEpB0ZsgzIVFq8aNWoPYnjz18xjmzBJ8@1dbE4NXyb@s8X32t8wLW9Q6cVfdWMX1pbbNlZLnRdMOn7SuEqYMy5tnmPeUfFmvqS3A@JbjngikqSRU82J@dwaRp7r8KVPpds3Z3yHe0ecLc0HdFKjxefroWfzRJVx1MkMph4c/Pu7Gv6IMtSL1JefPyw38/nUnDgipPp8Lls0cUp72/eJ1fpbDaxRCLOa5dwKQ6H45RKfIrprfwdUo6TZArzEMoRj87AtYgOx8eW4O@oZAelsxsDtd3Cn7EfqAK7JgcccI1PO6hsE31D2VW48aADBv0OStWAH1pltmDroIOOn/4B)

Output:

```
Tango hotel echo quebec uniform india charlie kilo bravo romeo oscar whiskey november foxtrot oscar xray juliett uniform mike papa echo delta oscar victor echo romeo tango hotel echo lima alfa zulu yankee delta oscar golf 
Juliett alfa charlie kilo delta alfa whiskey sierra lima oscar victor echo mike yankee bravo india golf sierra papa hotel india november xray oscar foxtrot quebec uniform alfa romeo tango zulu
```

Answer (score 2):

## IBM PC DOS 8088 machine language, 165 bytes

This is directly based on [gwaugh's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178442/17216), but I shaved off 26 bytes by omitting the `$` delimiters from the "NATO" word table and an extra 1 byte by not skipping the first character of the command-line parameter string (which will always be either `/` or   and thus will be ignored by the program anyway). The program ended up being exactly the same length to be able to process the table in this format (in which the words are delimited only by uppercase characters, which serve the double purpose of also being the second letter of each word), or 2 bytes longer if the output capitalization is kept the same as before. The table is 26 bytes smaller.

In the following program dump, concatenation by `:` is used to show each sequence of consecutive bytes corresponding to an instruction:

```
0000  BE:80:00 AC 91 AC 24:DF 8A:D0 2C:40 3C:1A 77:21  ······$···,@<·w!
0010  8A:F0 B4:02 CD:21 56 BE:34:01 AC A8:20 75:FB FE: ·····!V·4··· u··
0020 :CE 75:F7 8A:D0 CD:21 AC A8:20 75:F7 B2:20 CD:21  ·u····!·· u·· ·!
0030  5E E2:D2 C3 4C 66 61 52 61 76 6F 48 61 72 6C 69  ^···LfaRavoHarli
0040  65 45 6C 74 61 43 68 6F 4F 78 74 72 6F 74 4F 6C  eEltaChoOxtrotOl
0050  66 4F 74 65 6C 4E 64 69 61 55 6C 69 65 74 74 49  fOtelNdiaUliettI
0060  6C 6F 49 6D 61 49 6B 65 4F 76 65 6D 62 65 72 53  loImaIkeOvemberS
0070  63 61 72 41 70 61 55 65 62 65 63 4F 6D 65 6F 49  carApaUebecOmeoI
0080  65 72 72 61 41 6E 67 6F 4E 69 66 6F 72 6D 49 63  erraAngoNiformIc
0090  74 6F 72 48 69 73 6B 65 79 52 61 79 41 6E 6B 65  torHiskeyRayAnke
00A0  65 55 6C 75 40                                   eUlu@
```

Download the DOS NATO.COM executable:
[With uncorrected capitalization](https://kingbird.myphotos.cc/66950d6b63d68800ece9aab9bb71e83d/nato.com) (165 bytes)
[With clean capitalization](https://kingbird.myphotos.cc/961141a824d8438979a06634d2695dc0/nato.com) (167 bytes)
[Bonus version that capitalizes the first letter of each word the same as the input](https://kingbird.myphotos.cc/faef61580a56c11aef97099b54c05536/nato.com) (167 bytes)

Unassembled:

```
    .MODEL TINY            ; .COM program, maximum addressing space 65536 bytes
    .CODE
    ORG 100h
start:
    MOV  SI, 80h           ; Point SI to DOS PSP (Program Segment Prefix).
    LODSB                  ; Load command-line parameter (input string) length
                           ; into AL; assume AX=0 before this, which is true
                           ; in most versions of DOS; advance SI to first char
                           ; of parameter, which is either '/' or ' '.
    XCHG CX, AX            ; Set up loop counter with length of input string.
search:
    LODSB                  ; Load next character from [SI] into AL; advance SI.
    AND  AL, NOT ('A' XOR 'a')  ; Make this character uppercase.
    MOV  DL, AL            ; Save character for output. Move this before the
                           ; AND instruction to capitalize the first letter of
                           ; each word identically to how it is in the input.
    SUB  AL, 'A'-1         ; convert letter to one-based index (A=1, Z=26, etc)
    CMP  AL, 'Z'-'A'+1     ; Is this an alphabetical character?
    JA   notFound          ; If not, move to next character.
    MOV  DH, AL            ; Set up DH as our word-finding loop counter.
    MOV  AH, 02h           ; AH=02h, INT 21h: Write character to STDOUT
    INT  21h               ; Display first character of this NATO word.
    PUSH SI                ; Save our current position in the input string.
    MOV  SI, OFFSET table  ; Point LODSB to beginning of word data.
scanLoop:                  ; Find the word in the table corresponding to our
                           ; current character.
    LODSB                  ; Load next character from [SI] into AL; advance SI.
    TEST AL, 'A' XOR 'a'   ; Is this character uppercase?
    JNZ  scanLoop          ; If not, move to next character.
    DEC  DH                ; Delimiter (uppercase) found; decrement counter.
    JNZ  scanLoop          ; Keep looping until counter reaches 0.
    OR   AL, 'A' XOR 'a'   ; Make this character lowercase. This is not
                           ; required by the challenge's specification, and
                           ; this instruction can be removed.
wordLoop:
    MOV  DL, AL            ; Display next character from NATO word.
    INT  21h               ; (We still have AH=02h from before.)
    LODSB
    TEST AL, 'A' XOR 'a'   ; Is this character lowercase?
    JNZ  wordLoop          ; If so, continue the loop.
    MOV  DL, ' '           ; Display a space between words.
    INT  21h               ; (We still have AH=02h from before.)
    POP  SI                ; Restore our current position in the input string.
notFound:
    LOOP search            ; Move to next character in input string.
    RET
table   DB  'LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdia'
        DB  'UliettIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeo'
        DB  'IerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu'
        DB  '@'            ; Terminate the list to make sure that uninitialized
                           ; memory doesn't cause a problem.
    END start
```

Sample input:

```
>NATO The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
>NATO Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.
```

Output (165 byte version):

```
TAngo hOtel eCho qUebec uNiform iNdia cHarlie kIlo bRavo rOmeo oScar wHiskey nOvember fOxtrot oScar xRay jUliett uNiform mIke pApa eCho dElta oScar vIctor eCho rOmeo tAngo hOtel eCho lIma aLfa zUlu yAnkee dElta oScar gOlf 
JUliett aLfa cHarlie kIlo dElta aLfa wHiskey sIerra lIma oScar vIctor eCho mIke yAnkee bRavo iNdia gOlf sIerra pApa hOtel iNdia nOvember xRay oScar fOxtrot qUebec uNiform aLfa rOmeo tAngo zUlu
```

Clean-capitalization version (167 bytes):

```
Tango Hotel Echo Quebec Uniform India Charlie Kilo Bravo Romeo Oscar Whiskey November Foxtrot Oscar Xray Juliett Uniform Mike Papa Echo Delta Oscar Victor Echo Romeo Tango Hotel Echo Lima Alfa Zulu Yankee Delta Oscar Golf 
Juliett Alfa Charlie Kilo Delta Alfa Whiskey Sierra Lima Oscar Victor Echo Mike Yankee Bravo India Golf Sierra Papa Hotel India November Xray Oscar Foxtrot Quebec Uniform Alfa Romeo Tango Zulu
```

Clean-capitalization version with same capitalization as input (167 bytes):

```
Tango hotel echo quebec uniform india charlie kilo bravo romeo oscar whiskey november foxtrot oscar xray juliett uniform mike papa echo delta oscar victor echo romeo tango hotel echo lima alfa zulu yankee delta oscar golf 
Juliett alfa charlie kilo delta alfa whiskey sierra lima oscar victor echo mike yankee bravo india golf sierra papa hotel india november xray oscar foxtrot quebec uniform alfa romeo tango zulu
```

Comment: Nice work there!

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>108</s> 106 bytes

```
¸®¬Ë+u cg`ovem¼rws¯r°pawue¼cÙ o±ØÇ¯fmØtØkeyÙ°nkeewªuwlfaæ1ÃÉr¦e³ltawÖoxÉwolfÙ*lÙAawªieâ-¹µ±ke`qw
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=uK6syz11KStgb3Zlbbxyd3OvcrBwYXd1Zbxj2SBvsYCf2AHHr2aObdh0jtiRa2V52Z+wbmtlZXeqdXdsZmHmMcPJcqZls2x0YXfWnm94yZV3b2xm2Sps2UFhd6ppZeItjbm1sWtlYHHUZ0Rj&input=IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkIg==)

The backticks contains the compressed string:

```
ovemberwscarwapawuebecwomeowierrawangowniformwictorwhiskeywraywankeewuluwlfawravowharlieweltawchowoxtrotwolfwotelwndiawuliettwilowimawike
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>187</s> 183 bytes

```powershell
$args|% t*y|%{'AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJuliettKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu'-csplit'(?=[A-Z])'-like"$_*"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDrbsIwDIX/9ymiKiyA6COgjV3Z/T42pgmZ4tKItO6clIGAZ@/aDk3gP7ZObJ0vJ6MfZBujMYWMRFesCgk8teuGcO3lurFSPRPBMcOcTmJgo/EUjYOzMKZzWjgmd0Em6pNDc5lONFzl5Ypz19rQjU7gVs/wjuaYjJHvbQj8ABk85jjG8IkSpGeNzPAC6ZReUx0RJ286dMSDWNsZLt8Zlh@QzhCHuclVENrMaKeah93PXjD8aqnAlAa@HLX9TbHxvKOmJ8rqNFW//BCJAbGZqI5QNWA1VOBVr@B2ew1XDVvnPa1G3d2uM1AtryXWoiFWtam0HYmLDEOHkzJHOfpTGW1uXCkclPFKW4v@VvUD/Pb/j/z9N29T/AI)

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {
$args|% t*y|%{'AlfaBravoCharlieDeltaEchoFoxtrotGolfHotelIndiaJuliettKiloLimaMikeNovemberOscarPapaQuebecRomeoSierraTangoUniformVictorWhiskeyXrayYankeeZulu'-csplit'(?=[A-Z])'-like"$_*"}
}

@(
    ,('Hello World', 'Hotel', 'Echo', 'Lima', 'Lima', 'Oscar', 'Whiskey', 'Oscar', 'Romeo', 'Lima', 'Delta')
) | % {
    $s,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$result"-eq"$expected"
    "$result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True
Hotel Echo Lima Lima Oscar Whiskey Oscar Romeo Lima Delta
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>209</del> <del>205</del> 206 bytes

```php
while($l=$argv[1][$x++])echo$l!=' '?$l.preg_split('/([A-Z][a-z]*)/',ALfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUliettIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu,0,3)[31&ord($l)].' ':'';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc7baoNAEADQX7EgXW3Mjbw1DWEpBYUSIUUCFQkTHXVxdJbJNk3689bn83Jsa8e3vW2thyIsZ0HL4szQBKtwO/62hjDwaeeDNLd8XeT@fTYrQixb9ulppzy192lhBZvz1ZJxgVoGuZ5/FznM/4qXcKki/VnDEW4cg5DBD3Lw3nJ6d8IupTp1SIfKQDaZcwlx0kPSYXrD/oLyVYJoCxlesEx75GRKgh4aPpiapU9KxxKba4ePIzz00CFm9BOtok2Yb9bPLNV0D4vF1HxVajuOY4xE7J1YqPI00T8)

Output:

```php
"Hello World" => "HOtel eCho lIma lIma oScar WHiskey oScar rOmeo lIma dElta"
```

Or **195** bytes, with spaces not fully removed:

```php
while($l=$argv[1][$x++])echo$l,preg_split('/([A-Z][a-z]*)/',ALfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUliettIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu,0,3)[31&ord($l)].' ';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc7BaoNAEADQX/Eg1W1Mk5BjWoqUgkKJkCKFLhImOrqLo7NMtjbpz1vP7/KccfPzqzMuQBGWs6Bj8Xbs4q06zL/GEsYhvYQg3aR3lQ5vq1WlsDYcUuIEu/PVkfVxtIl1uv6uNKz/qke1iZL0o4UTTJyBkMV38vBmuLh5YV9QW3ikY2OhXMz7nDgfIO@xmHC4oHzWIKmDEi9YFwNyvuQgHTs@2pZlyGvPktlrj/cT3NOxRyzpJ9kme6X3uweWZjmr6ikKosM8zxkScfDFQs0/)

Output:

```php
"Hello World" => "HOtel eCho lIma lIma oScar   WHiskey oScar rOmeo lIma dElta"
```

Comment: Nice, but your latest edit introduced an off-by-one error. One way to fix it is to change `[31&ord($l)]` back to `[31&ord($l)-1]`, costing two bytes, but you can also fix it in just one byte by fully spelling out `ALfa`.

Comment: Whoops! Good catch and very clever fix. Thx @deadcode!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 179 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.match(/\w/g).map(c=>c+'LfaRavoHarlieEltaChoOxtrotOlfOtelNdiaUliettIloImaIkeOvemberScarApaUebecOmeoIerraAngoNiformIctorHiskeyRayAnkeeUlu'.match(/.[a-z]+/g)[parseInt(c,36)-10])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NaoNQEEb3fQp3KlbTUuimGJBSUCgRUlylWYzX8SeOjr13ojEvb920i6bLj3P4OCcYwSjdDOL3XOBCKFYZLibcmqADUbWz@Zw2lbuOwVHhVnn2ewl7GDkGTQ2@kcBrzelFNEtKZSpIu6KBbGUiCXHSQdJiOmKXo/5QoKMBMsxRpR1yglpD1Fe8a0rWXaKEddyYFuc9zFHfImZ0tn9CggP416O31hwG0AaTXhx1//Ts@o8PR3dR3BsmDIgrp3TsGInYmlhTYbuWZ9m2@3L3x7EEjVj/41sbclVgWdXNqaWu5@FLGzmP02W@/j4s3w)

Answer (score 0):

## TSQL, 313 bytes

Golfed:

```
DECLARE @ varchar(max)='Hello World' 

DECLARE @x INT=len(@)WHILE @x>0SELECT @=stuff(@,@x,1,substring(@,@x,1)+choose(ascii(substring(@,@x,1))%32,'lfa','eta','harlie','elta','cho','oxtrot','olf','otel','ndia','uliett','ilo','ima','ike','ovember','scar','apa','uebec','omeo','ierra','ango','niform','ictor','hiskey','ray','ankee','ulu')+';'),@x-=1PRINT @
```

Ungolfed:

```
DECLARE @ varchar(max)='Hello World' 

DECLARE @x INT=len(@)
WHILE @x>0
  SELECT @=stuff(@,@x,1,substring(@,@x,1)+choose(ascii(substring(@,@x,1))%32,
    'lfa','eta','harlie','elta','cho','oxtrot','olf','otel','ndia','uliett','ilo',
    'ima','ike','ovember','scar','apa','uebec','omeo','ierra','ango','niform',
    'ictor','hiskey','ray','ankee','ulu')+';'),
    @x-=1

PRINT @
```

**[Try it out](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/960926/phonetic-alphabet)**

Output ends with semicolon

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, <strike>228</strike> 225 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @mazzy

```
"$args".ToLower()-replace' '|% T*y|%{$a+=$_+((-split"lfa ravo harlie elta cho oxtrot olf otel ndia uliett ilo ima ike ovember scar apa uebec omeo ierra ango niform ictor hiskey ray ankee ulu")[('a'..'z').IndexOf($_)])+' '};$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY/RSsNAEEV/5RK2bNbQ/ID4riD4UvBBpEyTSbNkkgmTbW20fntcX@893MuZ9Ytt6Vlk2wpHdl6K@qCv/2kZ9sazUMMe/r7D4WG9734cVU/uWJXlfpklpkI6gtFV0ZNJZLAkQtMr9JZME1Q6aGLB1EbCJSMpIYoijoQ4MPTK44kNS0MGmjPDJ26gI2eGzQg0nRVT7NRGxCapoY/LwGv@XXM5MOfdSxE@Sk@@rv23D/XL1PLtrSvdMXyGKgv8Pjratu05myre1aT9Aw)

This is quite possibly the ugliest piece of code I have ever written. In addition, this can certainly get a lot shorter. In my defense, I'm still recovering from final exams.

Comment: `-split'lfa ravo ...'` is shorter because '\s' is splitter by default :)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 212 bytes

```php
while($c=ord($argn[$i++]))echo[_,Alpha,Bravo,Charlie,Delta,"Echo",Foxtrot,Golf,Hotel,India,Juliett,Kilo,Lima,Mike,November,Oscar,Papa,Quebec,Romeo,Sierra,Tango,Uniform,Victor,Whiskey,Xray,Yankee,Zulu][$c&31]," ";
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/54ab86322e7f3f06011aa3a889cfb8d9442b2a68).

Yields warnings in PHP 7.2; put array elements in quotes to fix.

Will print an underscore for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>309</s> 283 bytes

*-26 bytes thanks to @[ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

```c
*k[]={"lfa","ravo","harlie","elta","cho","oxtrot","olf","otel","ndia","uliett","ilo","ima","ike","ovember","scar","apa","uebec","omeo","ierra","ango","niform","ictor","hiskey","ray","ankee","ulu"};i;main(z,v)char**v;{for(;z=toupper(v[1][i]);i++)z>64&z<92&&printf("%c%s ",z,k[z-65]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU5BboMwEPxKZCkICBxatZEqmpzzgx4QB8dZwsqLjYxBjaN8va6Xy854dsY7qlYkzT3GUrfd6Smol6ISTq42wSAdISQC5FlWA6v21zvrmVDP0wMlMDdky5ICnpdI7MWRRdT8iV1hvIJLbFaSQU5bAq6geD3ClgDnWE6l@Gmwt25kXXnLoQFnDY@t42OzaYDt7iJeDTajRJOHai1UKl@Wa/NM@bwJJ2@XaQKXr@1b12JXNHg4FOF8/MjC99d7lk0Oje9zsVf7eSeqUOk21MfPZHzFGC9AZHc/1tHtT/Uk73OspZnxHw)