# First person to ever beat Classic Tetris

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

## Historic Tetris Achievement

[Blue Scuti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willis_Gibson) became the first ever human to beat the classic game of Tetris on NES.

Here's the Tetris [Kill Screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuJ5UuknsHU)

[image: Blue Scuti]

## Challenge

Output the following Tetris `Kill Screen` board (10x20 blocks)

```
EEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEE
EEEEGGEEEE
EEEEBGGEEE
EBEEBBGGEE
EBEGBBBGBE
EEEEEEEEEE
BBGEBBGGBB
BBBEBBEGBB
BBBBBBBGBE
GGEBBBBBBB
GGEGBGGBBB
BBEBBGGGBB
```

| Code | Color |
| --- | --- |
| B | Blue |
| G | Green |
| E | Black |

## Rules

There is no strict requirement to use the characters B, G, and E, or a specific board orientation, as long as the concept of the `Kill Screen` is preserved.

## Examples

```
 Original    Rotate 180°
██████████   ░░▓▓▓░░█░░
██████████   ░░░▓▓░▓█▓▓
██████████   ░░░░░░░█▓▓
██████████   █░▓░░░░░░░
██████████   ░░▓█░░█░░░
██████████   ░░▓▓░░█▓░░
██████████   ██████████
██████████   █░▓░░░▓█░█
██████████   ██▓▓░░██░█
████▓▓████   ███▓▓░████     Rotate left 90°        Rotate right 90°    
████░▓▓███   ████▓▓████   ██████████████░░█░░░   ░▓▓░░░██████████████
█░██░░▓▓██   ██████████   ████████████░█░░░░░░   ░▓▓░░░█░░███████████
█░█▓░░░▓░█   ██████████   ███████████▓▓█▓▓▓░░▓   ███░░▓██████████████
██████████   ██████████   ██████████▓▓░█▓█░░▓▓   ░▓░░███▓████████████
░░▓█░░▓▓░░   ██████████   █████████▓▓░░█░░░░▓▓   ░░░░░░█░░░▓█████████
░░░█░░█▓░░   ██████████   █████████▓░░░█░░░░░░   ▓▓░░░░█░░▓▓█████████
░░░░░░░▓░█   ██████████   ████████████▓███░░▓░   ▓▓░░█▓█░▓▓██████████
▓▓█░░░░░░░   ██████████   ██████████████▓░░███   ▓░░▓▓▓█▓▓███████████
▓▓█▓░▓▓░░░   ██████████   ███████████░░█░░░▓▓░   ░░░░░░█░████████████
░░█░░▓▓▓░░   ██████████   ██████████████░░░▓▓░   ░░░█░░██████████████

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1111111111  ..........
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1111111111  ..........
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1111111111  ..........
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1111111111  ..........
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1111111111  ..........
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1111111111  ..........
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1111111111  ..........
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1111111111  ..........
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1111111111  ..........
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0  1111221111  ....##....                            ""     
0 0 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0  1111022111  ....O##...  00000000000000220222      !""   
0 2 0 0 2 2 1 1 0 0  1011002211  .O..OO##..  00000000000020222222   !  !!""  
0 2 0 1 2 2 2 1 2 0  1012000201  .O.#OOO#O.  00000000000110111221   ! "!!!"! 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1111111111  ..........  00000000001120102211
2 2 1 0 2 2 1 1 2 2  0021002200  OO#.OO##OO  00000000011220222211  !!" !!""!!
2 2 2 0 2 2 0 1 2 2  0001001200  OOO.OO.#OO  00000000012220222222  !!! !! "!!
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 0  0000000201  OOOOOOO#O.  00000000000010002212  !!!!!!!"! 
1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2210000000  ##.OOOOOOO  00000000000000122000  "" !!!!!!!
1 1 0 1 2 1 1 2 2 2  2212022000  ##.#O##OOO  00000000000220222112  "" "!""!!!
2 2 0 2 2 1 1 1 2 2  0010022200  OO.OO###OO  00000000000000222112  !! !!"""!!
```

Comment: Put your challenges in Sandbox first unless you are sure there's no changes.

Comment: @qwr The whole point of the Sandbox is for *other people* to spot needed changes you missed/are unaware of. So please encorage poster to always use the Sandbox, regardless of what they're *sure of*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>695</s> 682 bytes

```
[S S S T    S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S S T   T   N
_Push_3_"][S N
S _Duplicate_3_"][S N
S _Duplicate_3_"][S S S T   S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S S S T    S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S T T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_\n][S S S T   S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S S T   T   N
_Push_3_"][S N
S _Duplicate_3_"][S S S T   S N
_Push_2_!][S S S T  T   N
_Push_3_"][S S S T  N
_Push_1_<space>][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3_"][S N
S _Duplicate_3_"][S S T T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_\n][S S S T   S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3_"][S N
S _Duplicate_3_"][S S T T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_\n][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S S S T    S N
_Push_2_!][S S S T  T   N
_Push_3_"][S S S T  S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S T T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_\n][S S S T   S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S S T   T   N
_Push_3_"][S S S T  N
_Push_1_<space>][S S S T    S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S S S T    S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S T T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_\n][S S S T   S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S S T   T   N
_Push_3_"][S N
S _Duplicate_3_"][S S S T   S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3_"][S S S T  S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S T T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_\n][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S S T   T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_\n][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S S S T    S N
_Push_2_!][S S S T  T   N
_Push_3_"][S S S T  S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S S T   T   N
_Push_3_"][S S S T  N
_Push_1_<space>][S S S T    S N
_Push_2_!][S S S T  N
_Push_1_<space>][S S T  T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_\n][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S S S T T   N
_Push_3_"][S N
S _Duplicate_3_"][S S S T   S N
_Push_2_!][S N
S _Duplicate_2_!][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S S S T S N
_Push_2_!][S S S T  N
_Push_1_<space>][S S T  T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_\n][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S S S T T   N
_Push_3_"][S N
S _Duplicate_3_"][S S S T   S N
_Push_2_!][S S S T  N
_Push_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S S T   T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_\n][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S S S T T   N
_Push_3_"][S N
S _Duplicate_3_"][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S S S N
_Push_0][S S S T    S S T   N
_Push_9][T  T   S _Store][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP1][S S T  T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_\n][S S S T   N
_Push_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S N
S _Duplicate_1_<space>][S S S N
_Push_0][T  T   T   _Retrieve][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][T    T   S _Store][N
T   S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_LOOP2][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP1][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP2][S S S T    T   T   T   T   N
_Push_31][T S S S _Add_top_two][T   N
S S _Output_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP2]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##lZHBCoQwDETPM1@RX5NFWG/CLuzndxNjJdpE0HqYDp3mJf29l@/8WafX3JqIQKjLBDbh@jAZdoDK6MScm77tOdS5@NfHeb02zw8FzhhZMzexbALVHDKclKvuZGB1eS1SsMXJM0UbX4gVYnwRnGp02xnVhN/FB9MQDWE7ho5ijZipDi3Mg0o/Ym/K/Nb@) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

Outputs with `! "` instead of `BEG` to save 13 bytes.
(Here the TIO for the old/longer program: [Try it online with `BEG` as output](https://tio.run/##lVFbCoAwDPtuTtGriQj6Jyh4/LlsUzu7CfqANmuadD3mZZ@2dRinEFRFFPFVRimAViBMJvFRJjdkiRnMaSaakwbRft36x0Bp3GvgJayT9kBfPH8Ntf7Lo3fUsvY1jbN7hS@Zjj27ALTd@U2h69JuRiqVC06FBEsz/LkSBUsTWwuDsxCMCEgGbg3@kDIZT0I4AQ).)

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Push the codepoint-integers minus 31 of string '!!"""!! !!\n
                                                !!!""!" ""\n
                                                !!!!!!! ""\n
                                                 !"!!!!!!!\n
                                                !!" !! !!!\n
                                                !!""!! "!!\n
                                                          \n
                                                 !"!!!" ! \n
                                                  ""!!  ! \n
                                                   ""!    \n
                                                    ""    '
a=9
Start LOOP1:
  Push the codepoint-integers minus 31 of string '\n
                                                            '
  a = a-1
  If a==0:
    Jump to LOOP2
  Go to next iteration of LOOP1

LOOP2:
  Add 31 to the top integer
  Print it as character with this codepoint to STDOUT
  Go to next iteration of LOOP2
```

The constant `31` is generated by [this Java program](https://tio.run/##fVLva9swEP2ev@J8n2Scmgy2D7UjSgsdGJYO6nQblDJkV03UObIny4Ew8renJ/9InG3UH6TH3Xvvzqd7FVtx8fr863DIC1HXsBBK/5kAVE1WqBxqKyxd21I9w4ZSLLVG6dXjEwjf0QC6ABhZN4UFDuJx9hS3GaUt1BtRFLJ2iURbuZImXFz/@Pnt@svD7RQSfhmPTQb2/WCG2OW/Pixv76OX0jBnqngSq/mHT7NYBUHfxqkRjji104oPWgCny3ZWQhZ1bYYraW8oUDP/KKd@X4BlnCsf8lJbpRvZ1Y2PDMup/LL8vlakrUQub5QWZtdVZtmF8uORG7Oh/N2IombVuAxQiyY0sirI4LMytWXVtAowvUtxpN@DLGoJ5zobmBHjiCpuh/AQpPImLKRe2TXzYX4c7aiRf6Y98h6928nmlE4ors5Ldme6q63chGVjw4qGYgvNsJNzDAbTAGN6QwySACECDN4bauL3Zf92Zuftt6z9hI5@Zft1eM/b7ZLuB7IVhp4X0xQDpjmfXSFGek7XEiM8PsywgXk0bLMtzyxd1l8Iuw5FVjPt@/9bNRvwfP7x8op8I/KPR/Mz0jZGEwPvsPuj/eFwcBlEd7Ykr8UT8Ai22EH0CHswWpcJBVqC5xH0CEIPvZ6LLt9@DmJLdYRWRfgN), based on [this Whitespace tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158232/52210).

Answer (score 10):

## C (gcc), <del>476</del> <del>395</del> <del>308</del> <del>283</del> <del>153</del> 151 bytes

*-130 bytes thanks to @Command Master

-2   bytes thanks to @ceilingcat*

Applying [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to the ascii-art.

```
*a=L"sssssssss7%77%-#'%#1s''%'1''Y%Y%%1''/'";b;main(c){for(;c=*a++;(b+=c/5-3)%20||puts(""))printf("[4%dm %*s",c%5,c/5,"[0m");}
```

[Try it online](https://godbolt.org/z/o8dr1YKbh)

**Output**

[image: cm]

[Linux Terminal](https://godbolt.org/z/sz3E1xn87)

[image: l_works_153]

Comment: I think it's fine to have ANSI output, as adding your own restrictions on top of the challenge is OK, but there are a few trivial byte saves—you can use a single character instead of `row`, and there are many spaces you can remove

Comment: [218 bytes](https://godbolt.org/z/369hzoWh1)

Comment: Hopefully it's possible we can get it < 200 bytes? :)

Comment: [156 bytes](https://godbolt.org/z/WPa86WvGz) (with colors!)

Comment: [155](https://godbolt.org/z/PYjvsaY77)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>114</s> 112 bytes

```python
x=int("cmlzatvntfmkheiwxpk0p5iob21d1xxc29",36)
c='0'*90
while x:c+=str(x%3);x//=3
while c:print(c[:10]);c=c[10:]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3CypsM_NKNJSSc3OqEkvK8krScrMzUjPLKwqyDQpMM_OTjAxTDCsqko0slXSMzTS5km3VDdS1LA24yjMyc1IVKqyStW2LS4o0KlSNNa0r9PVtjaEyyVYFRSCTk6OtDA1iNa2TbZOjDQ2sYiH2Qq2HOQMA)

This isn't winning any code golf, but it's an interesting concept I wanted to try out before. Basically it is the last 11 rows concatenated, interpreted as a base-3 number, then reversed. Of course, storing the data in the source code as a <s>hex</s> base-36 number wastes a lot of bits, and the printing and decoding can be optimized much further.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 106 bytes

```python
lambda i=200,x=int("2mwpsm5yo9be8gwx4tjcljqj9lx0jxigz",36):f(i-1,x//3)+str(x%3)+'​\n'[i%10<1]if i else''
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3s3ISc5NSEhUybY0MDHQqbDPzSjSUjHLLC4pzTSvzLZNSLdLLK0xKspJzsgqzLHMqDLIqMtOrlHSMzTSt0jQydQ11KvT1jTW1i0uKNCpUgQz1Rw3dMXnq0ZmqhgY2hrGZaQqZCqk5xanq6hAbVxUUgexI09DUhAgsWAChAQ)

This is the program rewritten as a function returning the result, based on l4m2's answer. Before the `\n` there's a ZWSP that is counted in the byte-count but technically means the string has a bunch of extra non-printing spaces.

Very rough constant generation code:

```python
b="""EEEEGGEEEE
EEEEBGGEEE
EBEEBBGGEE
EBEGBBBGBE
EEEEEEEEEE
BBGEBBGGBB
BBBEBBEGBB
BBBBBBBGBE
GGEBBBBBBB
GGEGBGGBBB
BBEBBGGGBB"""
b = b.replace('E','0').replace('G','1').replace('B','2')
b = b.replace('\n','')[::-1]
x = int(b,3)
print(hex(x))
```

Comment: And it ends up not bad XD

Comment: @l4m2 the constant is 175 bits, so 22 bytes of constant is a lower bound for this base-3 method without additional tricks.

Comment: Have you tried using a larger base? For instance base62 (26+26+10) or base 256 (an outright ascii string using `ord`)? Also, I wonder if numpy.base_repr or django.utils.baseconv.base62.decode could be useful, although that would be a different answer (under "python plus library" rather than just 'python')

Comment: @Stef base64 requires a library and python source files can't contain arbitrary bytes unless it's also Unicode (by default, maybe there is a python interpreter trick). I can read bytes from a file but I don't like doing that for codegolf answers.

Comment: *by Unicode I mean utf8 for python 3

Answer (score 6):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 98 bytes

```bash
repeat 9 <<<1111111111
for w (MJ4 M3D KS7 QY7 MS4 150Z 15LQ QZZ 19JR 1809 14OH)rev<<<$[[##3]36#$w]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3k4pSC1ITSxQsFWxsbAzhgCstv0ihXEHD18tEwdfYRcE72FwhMNJcwTfYRMHQ1CAKSPgEKgRGARmWXkEKhhYGlgqGJv4emkWpZUCDVKKjlZWNY43NlFXKYyE2QS2EWQwA)

Converts each line from base 36 to base 3. Each line is reversed, because no line ends with a `G` (`0`), so we can avoid needing to pad with zeroes.

[Generator](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3DdLyixSKFTQSilLLakqKFNxdnRQMDI0SNLlSkzPyFXTzFFSio5WVjc1ijZVVimNjFCD6oNoX3KxwBQJ3dxDJBSKcwGwuVycgE8wGMd2dgGwniAII4AIKgBU4OQGZTkCmK5TpBFXrDpIHAxDTHawUpACsC8iGOAAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 bytes

```
“ṚƝ*ẊḢ-PṇḃeḶ:@İñṇY¤kṂė’b3Ż94¡s⁵Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf9qZWxsef//4oCc4bmaxp0q4bqK4biiLVDhuYfhuINl4bi2OkDEsMOx4bmHWcKka@G5gsSX4oCZYjPFuzk0wqFz4oG1Wf//)

A niladic link that outputs the kill screen with 0 for E, 1 for G and 2 for B. A base-250 encoded integer that is converted to base 3, prepended with 94 zeros, split into pieces length 10 and then joined with new lines.

Answer (score 5):

## [Funge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 165 bytes

```
 9\wv>58k:9k.a,1+:
    v3> ^j3:k35,a<
  2p>53k:3k.7:..'^e
v>k.2277722523k:772757725k:57752725k:227522523k:7722572258k:527222752555772255255557725k.a,
<,a.k9p10-1_@#:g10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCsIwDEDP9isKHjy4lTUldA2j@CEyqVAHBkYvTvz6mtWDhySPvITknh@vdcl9GPvyaVirDtf3FnFkCmxSZ8@kDpuLen46YoddmpTWUCI6JsfGkzGnOastsgHw3gMgiBLwKAmZpCA0kgH8e8A95NBum0LE1m/025YX1NQlw6HYobe3y5EWO9T6BQ)

Instead of `B`, `G`, and `E`, this program outputs `2`, `7`, and `5`.

Contains a tab, which does not seem to work in code blocks, so here is a hex dump:

```
00000000: 2039 5c77 763e 3538 6b3a 396b 2e61 2c31   9\wv>58k:9k.a,1
00000010: 2b3a 0a09 7633 3e20 5e6a 333a 6b33 352c  +:..v3> ^j3:k35,
00000020: 613c 0a20 2032 703e 3533 6b3a 336b 2e37  a<.  2p>53k:3k.7
00000030: 3a2e 2e27 5e65 0a76 3e6b 2e32 3237 3737  :..'^e.v>k.22777
00000040: 3232 3532 336b 3a37 3732 3735 3737 3235  22523k:772757725
00000050: 6b3a 3537 3735 3237 3235 6b3a 3232 3735  k:57752725k:2275
00000060: 3232 3532 336b 3a37 3732 3235 3732 3235  22523k:772257225
00000070: 386b 3a35 3237 3232 3237 3532 3535 3537  8k:5272227525557
00000080: 3732 3235 3532 3535 3535 3737 3235 6b2e  72255255557725k.
00000090: 612c 0a3c 2c61 2e6b 3970 3130 2d31 5f40  a,.<,a.k9p10-1_@
000000a0: 233a 6731 30                             #:g10
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
ＧTχE⪪”{“⌈K→◧ψＭ^≡Ｎq§d5Ｇ↑℅a⁰≔)⦃L+y≡”χ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gP6cyPT9PwypER8HQQEdB3VVd05oroCgzr0QjuCAns0RDyRUI3N1docAJwnQCIgjTydXdCch0ckUAIBcs6wQCQJYrhOUEUecOkoRw3IEyCGXuIKYSyB2amtb////XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: The `ＧTχE` draws a `10×10` square of `E`s, leaving the cursor at the bottom left, so that the `10`th line will be overwritten as the bottom `11` lines are then drawn by splitting a compressed string into rows of `10` characters.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 108 bytes

```perl
say for('}'x13 .']W}MJWeJURW]JMOZOJ}eROMRWjMRMOzROJMWMzWMOJWjMR_R')=~s,.,($&&G)x((63&ord$&)/8),gre=~/.{10}/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjdCoIwGADQV/FC9gO2OcToxuvgg4/BIAaBRNASI5psEWbMR2/RuTyTC/c253h@F1cfGE10Vk0haG8TgnVwMLYH1EcNyRmNxt7QoF6MBrS4WNTwn5OhvFtjJSpWErLnM2PbhvhwKQmXO14NwXWrFB9VJznk/PXTc/SPmDf4aoWqfw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>84</s> <s>83</s> 78 bytes

```ruby
puts (?0*94+0x7241ea9db46487237308d479dcb396cc036e301ec3.to_s(3)).scan /.{10}/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN_0KSkuKFTTsDbQsTbQNKsyNTAxTEy1TkkzMTCzMjYzNjQ0sUkzMLVOSk4wtzZKTDYzNUo0NDFOTjfVK8uOLNYw1NfWKkxPzFPT1qg0NavUhpkINh1kCAA)

Ports Jelly, which to my surprise is extremely short in Ruby.

Previous solutions:

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 86 bytes

```ruby
puts [674,5102,9124,30937,96952,116639,2264,459,18212,716].map{_1.to_s(3).rjust 20,?0}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN8MKSkuKFaLNzE10TA0NjHQsDY1MdIwNLI3NdSzNLE2NdAwNzcyMLXWMjMxMdExMLXUMLYwMjXTMDc1i9XITC6rjDfVK8uOLNYw19YqySotLFIwMdOwNaiGmQy2BWQYA)

Outputs the board rotated 90 degrees, rough port of my Japt solution.

### [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>119</s> 114 bytes

```ruby
puts [716,18212,459,2264,116639,96952,30937,9124,5102,674].map{_1.to_s(3).rjust(20,?0).chars}.transpose.map{_1*''}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc5BCsIwEEDRq7hrK2PITJJJs_IgIqWKIoI2ZJJFkZ7ETRd6KG_jwrr_8N_zlcphnOd3yedN-0mxZFntPDJgS0hgXQAitoDIbAIEDo7A6GA8BCQLDjUBe7tXtz4-OlR56KQ2jUrXIrkmDVvdqOOlTzKpnPq7xEFOS7yuqul3XgB_yBc)

Un-rotated version of above solution.

Comment: @vengy You're right, I made a small typo - 96 leading zeroes where there should have been 94. I just edited the post, it's fixed now.

Comment: The rotate left 90 degrees (86 bytes) looks correct but it's flipped incorrectly. See my examples section for the correct orientation. It's tricky visualizing the rotated boards. ;)

Comment: @vengy Good catch, fortunately another easy fix - just had to reverse the array.

Comment: Nice work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Assembly (nasm, x64, linux) 322 bytes

```
b dq 0,0,0,0,01ADB000000000h,0BEF21AC00033838h,0BFE67E8h,8455DEDA83BD4C42h,41B2938E84746B28h,8343133241A32656h
global _start
_start:mov r8,b
mov bl,20
l:mov eax,[r8]
mov rsi,rsp
mov rcx,10
mov[rsi],cl
r:mov dl,0
mov r9,10
div r9
add dl,48
dec si
mov[rsi],dl
loop r
mov al,1
mov dx,11
mov di,1
syscall
add r8,4
dec bl
jnz l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5dbsMgEITfOQUH2Er82SF9M7FziSiqwFi1o3WcQlQlvbwLOFXhgW9nZ0bYGIfZ4fPtauO8ro76L8rgdXnTGvZ3RmCmOwreHNIgpZY6K8eu3nWJtKqqtmsbLU2rDkqMoLgRe6k7rXaqNiJ7pJJcSqF4I0Vd1SP5xMVZpB/xbsOdbM/7vHzToMGRDA5BMIJFHOwDTkGfyyLECUK8bdw/gLOMpySfoUcSSsIjsM2xzwY/ZSLW@7xRmvihp3H6D3okuCw3GkrIIvACPtW/aEpSfMbeIpae9FFVahySy/WH4rr@Ag)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.10.10, 164 bytes(UTF-8)

---

###### Definitely not the shortest, but oh well.

```python
a="\n#.~"
for i in"ªªªZV¨ªªfU¡ªª¾ªª~n=ªª~Yõ¨ªzeU¡ªªºZªªª^*ªªjY}¨ªªjõ":w=ord(i)*4;print("".join(a[(w:=w//4)&3]for i in a),end="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9FWKSZPWa9OiSstv0ghUyEzT@nQKhCMCju0AkSnhR5aCBbZV3@oF8Soy7MFU5GHt4JUVKXCFOyKOtQO0RunBSKzImshRmQd3sqoZFVum1@UopGpqWViXVCUmVeioaSkl5WfmaeRGK1RbmVbrq9voqlmHAtzhkKipk5qXoqtkpLm//8A)

Outputs a 90deg rotated board, with some extra newlines.

### How

I packed 4 characters into a byte, using 2 bits for each character(`#`,`.`,`~`, or `\n`).
Then, I just use `ord` to convert the ASCII junk back into integers, then unpack it.

##### Clever things:

- Since `for i in range(4)` is obviously way too long, I used `for i in a`, as `a` (coincidentally) has a `len` of 4, and I don't need the value of `i`(the second i) anyway.
- `*4` when assigning `w`, then `(w:=w//4)` in the loop, making use of the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions). I originally had `a[w&3+0*(w:=w//4)]`, but then I realized I can just multiply the initial value of `w` by 4.

###### Misc note: I checked, `print(*(genexpr),sep="",end="")` is longer than `print("".join(genexpr),end="")`(by exactly 1 character)

Comment: Nice. I'd like to see the output. Could you add a link such as [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##HchBDoIwEADAu69oOAgNxFQQERU@YjwIVruIW1JBF1/g1ZjwQD5SjXOcpm@VxshaysTkoaCWjLYLIdaNAWw9151VGtBzxuE1Du9x@Di7/xcg41XdY2pkebvHHc1V2dTFM7mQxqS9HguZ/qLq3CBa8jyHabQ/acOAATJzwLP0KCA/FEHIOd@Qn4XC2i8). To create your own demo, goto [TIO](https://tio.run/), choose the Python language and cut N paste your code. Thanks!

Comment: @vengy [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9FWKSZPWa9OiSstv0ghUyEzT@nQKhCMqj20AkSnHt56aCFE6ND0Q10g@vCqLFkQHRcZClJzeFfq4amHFoNVzI8@1A9WsuvwPlOILoiiQ6uyIhmVrMpt84tSNDI1tUysC4oy80o0lJT0svIz8zQSozXKrWzL9fVNNNWMY2FuUUjU1EnNS7FVUtL8/x8A "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online"). Will edit into answer now.

Comment: It's very close but the output screen needs to be flipped vertically. See one of the 90 degrees rotation examples in the challenge.

Comment: @vengy Fixed. Apparently it became shorter??

Comment: Did you update the link? I'm seeing the old output.

Comment: @vengy I thought the link contents would update. Well. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9FWKSZPWa9OiSstv0ghUyEzT@nQKhCMCju0AkSnhR5aCBbZV3@oF8Soy7MFU5GHt4JUVKXCFOyKOtQO0RunBSKzImshRmQd3sqoZFVum1@UopGpqWViXVCUmVeioaSkl5WfmaeRGK1RbmVbrq9voqlmHAtzhkKipk5qXoqtkpLm//8A "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: Looks great now, well done! +1 for keeping the solution < 200 bytes too!

Answer (score 2):

## Python (3), <del>229</del> <del>142</del> <del>132</del> 125 bytes

```
x=0
while x<400:print(''.join("█░▓"[int('bie58lyn9recsv5ux1hcplbz7kxon7tmdbe9cplju',36)>>i&3]for i in range(x,x+20,2)));x+=20
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##HchBDoIwEADAu69oOAgNxFQQERU@YjwIVruIW1JBF1/g1ZjwQD5SjXOcpm@VxshaysTkoaCWjLYLIdaNAWw9151VGtBzxuE1Du9x@Di7/xcg41XdY2pkebvHHc1V2dTFM7mQxqS9HguZ/qLq3CBa8jyHabQ/acOAATJzwLP0KCA/FEHIOd@Qn4XC2i8)

**Output (Rotated 180°)**

```
▓▓░░░▓▓█▓▓
▓▓▓░░▓░█░░
▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█░░
█▓░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓
▓▓░█▓▓█▓▓▓
▓▓░░▓▓█░▓▓
██████████
█▓░▓▓▓░█▓█
██░░▓▓██▓█
███░░▓████
████░░████
██████████
██████████
██████████
██████████
██████████
██████████
██████████
██████████
██████████
```

Comment: 229 bytes to decode a 200 character grid?

Comment: @qwr 220 chars+23 (docstring + print)=243 chars required undecoded

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>159</s> <s>156</s> 153 bytes

```javascript
console.log('94E2G8EB2G4EB2E2B2G3EBEG3BGB11E2BGE2B2G5BE2BEG9BGBE2GE7B2GEGB2G5BE2B3G2B'.replace(/(\d+)(.)/g,(_,t,c)=>c.repeat(t)).replace(/.{10}/g,`$&
`))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYpBCsIwEEX3nkNsBmNq04p2oYvAMJcQbEhDqZSmtMGNePY4CuJm/vz3390@7OLmfoq7MbQ@JRfGJQxeDaETWV2hphMaTRUf1PyUaJBKQ6YouNOXHQwHUs2UfTwyQvrxkrTJ1OynwTovcnFttyAU5J0UNxmlg/PFfWZvo4gAf1M9i/2LtWa9WTUAKb0B)

Comment: Is that a RLE? Nice

Comment: yep, TIL that's what they're called

Comment: Impressive to implement it without knowing what it's called!

Comment: You can match `\d+` instead of `\d*` to obviate the need for handling `1` as a special case for [153 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYpBCsIwEEX3nkNsBmNq04p2oYvAMJcQbEhDqZSmtMGNePY4CuJm/vz3390@7OLmfoq7MbQ@JRfGJQxeDaETWV2hphMaTRUf1PyUaJBKQ6YouNOXHQwHUs2UfTwyQvrxkrTJ1OynwTovcnFttyAU5J0UNxmlg/PFfWZvo4gAf1M9i/2LtWa9WTUAKb0B).

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 92 bytes

```javascript
f=(x=200,n=0xe482b7c850b79b07c4080ea138643fd606dacb4523n)=>x?f(x-1,n/3n)+n%3n+[`
`[x%10]]:''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfdCsIgGADQ@95jTNlWnz9TC6wHGYOp0yjGZ7QI3946d@fpvm4P78frM2BeYw0Z97zF45bvhNRkSbEcoEcLJUrDvQ5mBK/PHnSQYCA6JoySIq0K1OqClyMXSO213BIpA@vx9G@HjcBuWg7LVBoG83xp20oJpfUH)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 146 bytes

```javascript
x=>(x=`EEEEEEEEEE
`).repeat(9)+`EEEEGGEEEE
EEEEBGGEEE
EBEEBBGGEE
EBEGBBBGBE
${x}BBGEBBGGBB
BBBEBBEGBB
BBBBBBBGBE
GGEBBBBBBB
GGEGBGGBBB
BBEBBGGGBB`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcvBCoMwDAbge5/DQ4LofQc9BEpeo8UV2RArKqMw9uxdEsQcwkf@P@/4ice0v7azW/Mz1SmvR15Sv@QZoJZhhDIEf48L2O9pS/GEB7YWMFugi8zOk9CsZBKTd823/ESWEDm5Cv1FukqsuY2SraoF@xKHioBY/w)

- - 

Comment: Designating empty blocks as 0 is a nice touch. Some solutions are using 1 which kinda triggers me. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 112 bytes, 109 bytes or 68 bytes

Prompts for characters to display. 3 bytes can be saved if a matrix of the integers 1 2 3 is allowed. Simply delete the first 2 characters and the last.

```
⎕[⍉(2×b⊤n,48 24 12 68 0 140 4 4 768 856 28)+((b←10⍴2)⊤(n←9⍴0),0 32 304 314 0 819 947 1018 127 39 867)+z←10 20⍴1]
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##HY5NCsIwEIX3OcXsTGgLmSQ2yVYQERQPIC7aSkUoVehKD@AfVNyIF/AI3sCb5CJ1KrN5j8f3Mdm@StaHrNptkqLKmmZbdOH@nM/C6aEZpemCErJwOZf9sAztlavvKw@3dx0bB8oAKkgdSEAjwdBZam6YgnIi4jzveRnajxLE8JqqpyZFLEEr0NKARkO4Qw/eWECJjpwWtAeXWhEd/wZQvQRXHb3CupINxpPRgMEP)

Alternatively using the base 3 approach with the integers 0 1 2 representing E G B

```
(9 10⍴0)⍪(11⍴3)⊤376 9124 594 4417 146893 166580 55205 18212 2551 337
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##Dcw7CgIxEADQPqeYcrdYyGRm8jmCoHiGsLIiBBS28gKuCCs23sDK2hPNRWK6V718KcPhmsv5OIwlz/NprPp877Z6e5Fp2uyb0Oh9mWqXAK2uP9vr@u0QG6nXx4eCh4SOQRIDMwZA9jERoPcSLYg4K4DRoQMngkAUahtNnYyBPw)

Comment: I cannot conceive of APL not being an elaborate practical joke that just went a bit too far. It's a cool language, but the typographic presentation is just a nasty-looking string :(

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Imagine you've never looked at an arithmetic expression before. Those +'s and -'s are probably pretty nasty-looking too. Of course, you learn arithmetic and then it becomes second nature. If you only speak English and you look at something written in Chinese, just because Chinese is foreign to your eyes doesn't mean it's 'nasty'. Same goes for APL vs. more common programming languages—when you learn APL, there's nothing nasty about it. Sorry if this comes off as aggressive, I don't mean it that way :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>50</s> 49 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`mcnhp4 bn26 3hsvn2Ô©u6pn8t4n4v l2`qÍ®nH3ÃùT20 Õ·
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YG1jbmhwNJpibjI2jTNoc3ZuMtSpdTZwbjh0NG40doFsMmBxza5uSDPD%2bVQyMCDVtw)

My idea was to compress the 10 columns as base-3, left-pad each with zeroes to length 20, and transpose. I think this is more optimal than compressing the 11 rows as base-3 and prepending 9 rows of zeroes, which seems to be the strategy most submissions are using right now.

The idea used by Nick Kennedy's clever Jelly solution doesn't translate to Japt because it doesn't have support for bigints without hooking into JS, and when you leave Japt-land you don't get compression, so the program ends up quite a bit longer.

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 47 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`l2n4v8t4nu6pn2Ô©3hsvn26ebnhp4nmc`qÍ®nH3ÃùT20
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=YGwybjR2gTh0NG51NnBuMtSpM2hzdm4yNo1lYm5ocDRubWNgcc2ubkgzw/lUMjA)

Output rotated 90 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 104 bytes

```
≡(&p⊏:".O#"⇌)⬚0≡(≡/(+×2)↯⊟:2⌈÷2⧻.)⋯⊂⊚9+.640_1184_66856_68940_0_337197_345357_349516_169301_167093_332973
```

[Pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4omhKCZw4oqPOiIuTyMi4oeMKeKsmjDiiaEo4omhLygrw5cyKeKGr-KKnzoy4oyIw7cy4qe7Linii6_iioLiipo5Ky42NDBfMTE4NF82Njg1Nl82ODk0MF8wXzMzNzE5N18zNDUzNTdfMzQ5NTE2XzE2OTMwMV8xNjcwOTNfMzMyOTczCg==)

Outputs the following:

```
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
....##....
....O##...
.O..OO##..
.O.#OOO#O.
..........
OO#.OO##OO
OOO.OO.#OO
OOOOOOO#O.
##.OOOOOOO
##.#O##OOO
OO.OO###OO
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 46 bytes

```
0X94.(A*"!`V(;O01U	_3^R@=Mc,c"FDh)TB3<>t
```

The code contains unprintable characters which do not display correctly on StackExchange. Here's a hexdump:

```
00000000: 3058 3934 2e28 412a 2203 2160 5628 3b4f  0X94.(A*".!`V(;O
00000010: 300c 3155 095f 330e 5e52 4016 3d4d 632c  0.1U._3.^R@.=Mc,
00000020: 1a08 6322 4644 6829 5442 333c 3e74       ..c"FDh)TB3<>t
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbo5S7IKlpSVpuhY39QwiLE30NBy1lJgVE8I0rP0NeAxDOeON-eKCHMRsfZN1pDiSldxcMjRDnIxt7EoguqCaF0BpAA)

#### Explanation

Basically the same idea as [Nick Kennedy's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269414/16766), though Pip doesn't have the same base decompression builtin:

```
0X94.(A*"..."FDh)TB3<>t
                         t is 10; h is 100 (implicit)
        "..."            String of characters
      A*                 Get ASCII code of each
             FDh         Treat those as base-100 digits and convert to base 10
     (          )TB3     Convert to base 3
0X94.                    Prepend string of 94 zeros
                    <>t  Group into chunks of length 10
                         Print each on a separate line (-l flag)
```

I experimented with several bases and found 100 to give the best results. It's not the most efficient compression, but saving two bytes by writing `h` instead of `100` makes up for that.

Answer (score 2):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/yasepl-esolang), <s>131</s> 130 bytes

```
=m)"1"=a;m,10<<<<<<<<<;m,4~#44<~>944111#19>11994411>1914999491;m,10<=g;"9",2~#41~#44<~#91~#14<~~~>9491#441~~~>9#44149449<~#m~#444~
```

really annoying code but here's the output:

```
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111441111
1111944111
1911994411
1914999491
1111111111
9941994499
9991991499
9999999491
4419999999
4414944999
9919944499
```

uses 1, 4, and 9

edit : fixed an inconsistency

Comment: @vengy oh my! ill fix that now

Comment: @vengy it has been fixed ,

Comment: Tetris for @madeforlosers!

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 100 bytes

```
E93G1E7BG1E3BE1B1G1E2BEGB2GBE10B1GEB1G1B4EB1EGB8GBEG1EB6G1EGBG1B4EB1G2B1
\d+
$*
+`(.)1
$1$1
!`.{10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy9XS2N3Q1dwJSBg7uRo6GQIZRk6u7k5G7kCuAZDvChJzMgFSQFELoChQhZOZO4gHFXc3cjLkiknR5lLR4tJO0NDTNORSMVQx5FJM0Ks2NKj9//@/blkOAA) Explanation: Inspired by @mekb's JavaScript answer.

```
E93G1E7BG1E3BE1B1G1E2BEGB2GBE10B1GEB1G1B4EB1EGB8GBEG1EB6G1EGBG1B4EB1G2B1
```

Insert the RLE compressed string.

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
+`(.)1
$1$1
```

Perform RLE decoding.

```
!`.{10}
```

Split into rows of `10` characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `j`, 77 bytes

```
90'e×"∧.€¯uэuꜝ!¹»ġ«ᶳ⊻)pṚnṘᵞΘṆuĿġɾ⌐5Ṙ}Ч∥•Ɠ₌ᶳ¿⌈X¥¿₀Ḥ₉ỌŀoṆ~2JᶪNgWyZ∨ᵏᵘ#Ṡ=<W„J₀Ẇ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJqIiwiIiwiOTAnZcOXXCLiiKcu4oKswq910Y116pydIcK5wrvEocKr4baz4oq7KXDhuZpu4bmY4bWezpjhuYZ1xL/Eocm+4oyQNeG5mH3Qp+KIpeKAosaT4oKM4bazwr/ijIhYwqXCv+KCgOG4pOKCieG7jMWAb+G5hn4ySuG2qk5nV3la4oio4bWP4bWYI+G5oD08V+KAnkrigoDhuoZcbiIsIiIsIlxuIiwiMy40LjEiXQ==)

90 'e's then the rest of the board as a string, split into chunks of 10

will try to do an algorithmic approach later

Comment: Ruby’s just a byte longer than Vyxal?? :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 32 bytes

```
"ṁṘkƓ₳İᵛᵂƛ»Ω7∥I»;ᶤḌᶠĖꜝ“3y₅dÞ0₀Ẇ'
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJcIuG5geG5mGvGk+KCs8Sw4bWb4bWCxpvCu86pN+KIpUnCuzvhtqThuIzhtqDEluqcneKAnDN54oKFZMOeMOKCgOG6hiciLCIiLCIiLCIzLjQuMSJd)

This is roughly a port of Nick Kennedy's Jelly answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>34</s> 33 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•{Žúƶ
Í‹¼šÎëPšpUθrćQ´β•3B¾94×ìTô»
```

<s>Outputs `012` for `BEG`/blue-black-green respectively.</s>
-1 byte thanks to *@noodleMan* by using `012` for `EGB`/black-green-blue instead.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AUMAvP9vc2FiaWX//@KAonvFvcO6xrYKw43igLnCvMWhw47Dq1DFoXBVzrhyxIdRwrTOsuKAojNCwr45NMOXw6xUw7TCu///)

**Explanation:**

```python
•{Žúƶ
Í‹¼šÎëPšpUθrćQ´β•
            # Push compressed integer 166987503168216280220890692936947577852890694295235
 3B         # Convert it to base-3: 1100000000211000020022110002012221200000000000221022112222202201222222222120110222222211012112222202211122
   ¾94×     # Push a string of 94 "0"s
       ì    # Prepend it
        Tô  # Split it into parts of size 10
          » # Join this list by newlines
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210), to understand why `•{Žúƶ\nÍ‹¼šÎëPšpUθrćQ´β•` is `166987503168216280220890692936947577852890694295235`.

Comment: Alternative 34, maybe 33 if there's a 1-char that can push `0`? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUMAvP9vc2FiaWX//@KAonvFvcO6xrYKw43igLnCvMWhw47Dq1DFoXBVzrhyxIdRwrTOsuKAojNCMCA5NMOXw6xUw7TCu/// "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @noodleman Thanks. And `¾` is 0 by default, as well as `N` outside of loops. Although in this case, the `0 94` could also be `0₃<`. :)

Comment: Cool, never used 05AB1E before but seems pretty easy to pick up coming from other stack-based languages. (The program I posted was just copy-pasting parts of your explanation, but using the integer from my Vyxal and Nick Kennedy's Jelly)

Comment: @noodleman Yeah, 05AB1E isn't too hard to start with when you're familiar with stack-based languages. Of course, little tricks and [golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96361/tips-for-golfing-in-05ab1e) will come with experience, but feel free to make some 05AB1E answers and perhaps I can find something to golf further. (Or perhaps you find something more to golf in my answers like this one. ;D)

Answer (score 1):

## Pascal (FPC), 232 bytes

On 6 June 1984, the first Tetris version was written in [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)) for the Electronica 60.

```
var i:Byte;begin for i:=1 to 9 do WriteLn('EEEEEEEEEE');WriteLn('EEEEGGEEEE'#10'EEEEBGGEEE'#10'EBEEBBGGEE'#10'EBEGBBBGBE'#10'EEEEEEEEEE'#10'BBGEBBGGBB'#10'BBBEBBEGBB'#10'BBBBBBBGBE'#10'GGEBBBBBBB'#10'GGEGBGGBBB'#10'BBEBBGGGBB');end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcwxC8IwEAXgv3LgUDsodtTg8qDc4u4c21QCkpQ2CP76mJyN1tu@d@9u1HOnH7th7GJ86onsCa9g1M3craPB5@DcUPB0pN7TdbLBXNy2ar9T1eovZZZ00xyEEH@IRHEhIxm/8vIxMy2kDCxEYrsiVrecuzKFLKelLJ/yba2M6/cxvgE)

**Challenge**

Can the code be modified to < 200 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

## [Javascript (V8)](https://v8.dev), 134 bytes

```js
for(x of"@@@@@@@@@Ԁी@")print("0".repeat(10-(m=((v=x.codePointAt(0))<65?0:v).toString(4)).length)+m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SKNCIT9NyQEGrjQ8WNrwYcHKCR8Wrprh8GnJylmfVqyY9WnVqhkfJ61a9XHi0lWfFi2dpaRZUJSZV6KhZKCkV5RakJpYomFooKuRa6uhUWZboZecn5IakA9U4FiiYaCpaWNmam9gVaapV5IfXALUl65hoqmpl5Oal16Soamdq/n/PwA)

My first post! :3 Might as well start here because I'm a tetris fanatic

Comment: Tetris for @madeforlosers! Looks good, nice work.